# Why is \baselineskip not inserted before an \unvbox?

Tags: tex-core, boxes

It seems that `\setbox0=\vbox{\hbox{abc}}\unvbox0` is not equivalent to `\hbox{abc}`: the former does not insert a `\baselineskip` in the following situation.

```
\vbox{% 
  \hbox{XY}% 
  \hbox{abc}% 
  \hbox{def}
}

\vbox{% missing baselineskip before \unvbox0
  \hbox{XY}%
  \setbox0=\vbox{\hbox{abc}}%
  \unvbox0
  \hbox{def}
}
```

A solution might be

```
\vbox{% the baselineskip is inserted when we write \box0, then remove it.
  \hbox{XY}%
  \setbox0=\vbox{\hbox{abc}}%
  \box0
  \setbox2=\lastbox
  \unvbox2
  \hbox{def}
}
```

but is it really the right way to do it?

For information, I am trying to emulate the behaviour of `\halign` with hand-made boxes, and I don't think that I will be able to put the `\hbox{abc}` (corresponding to rows) directly on the current vertical list since the rows need to all be read and the glue left unset, until the end of the tabular is reached and we can know the width of each column. Resetting the glue requires me to go through the list of row boxes, `\unhbox` them, `\unhbox` and re-`\hbox` each cell, etc.

```
\bye
```

Comment: I like the `\bye` there. =) egreg answered your question, but one possibility might be setting `\baselineskip=0pt \lineskip=0pt` and the inserting a `\strut` similar to what `array` does.

Comment: @TH. I am trying to be as general as possible, so using `\prevdepth` is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

At the start of a `\vbox` the parameter `\prevdepth` is set to -1000pt and, when you do `\unvbox`, this value inhibits the interline glue. You must reinstate the correct `\prevdepth` in the `\vbox`:

```
\showboxbreadth=1000
\tracingonline=1

\setbox0=\vbox{
  \hbox{XY}
  \hbox{abc}
  \hbox{def}
}

\showbox0 \box0

\setbox0=\vbox{
  \hbox{XY}\dimen255=\prevdepth
  \setbox0=\vbox{\prevdepth=\dimen255 \hbox{abc}}
  \unvbox0
  \hbox{def}
}

\showbox0 \box0
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to `\prevdepth`.

Answer (score 9):

A different solution than keeping track explicitly of `\prevdepth` is to use `\lastbox`: this primitive removes the last box (here `\hbox{abc}`) from the current list, and, since we are not doing anything with it, puts it back in the list. TeX then inserts the baselineskip, using the correct value of `\prevdepth` (even in weird cases where I manually alter `\prevdepth` after `\hbox{XY}`).

Of course, this solution is less general than egreg's answer, because that only works if the saved box contains a single box (this was true in my case).

```
\showboxbreadth=1000
\tracingonline=1

\setbox0=\vbox{
  \hbox{XY}
  \hbox{abc}
  \hbox{def}
}

\showbox0 \box0

\setbox0=\vbox{
  \hbox{XY}
  \setbox0=\vbox{\hbox{abc}}
  \unvbox0
  \lastbox % <= this
  \hbox{def}
}

\showbox0 \box0
```

Comment: One problem is that if the box has been moved left or right (for example with `\moveleft` or `\parshape`), this will be lost with the `\lastbox`.