# Can't I put a list inside an \lrbox?

Tags: lists, boxes

I want to have a list in my saved box. Why doesn't the following work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\newenvironment{myenv}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
  \begin{list}{}{}%
}{%
  \end{list}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \usebox{\mybox}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

Must I use a `\minipage`?

Comment: `lrbox` is the environment form of `\sbox`; you can insert a `minipage` in `lrbox`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The evironment `lrbox` uses the a simple `hbox` to save the contents. So you have no line breaks. Instead of using lrbox (internal it is a `savebox`) you can also use the command `\setbox` in combination with `vbox` to allow line breaks.

```
\newenvironment{myenv}{%
 \setbox\mybox=\vbox\bgroup%
  \begin{list}{}{}%
}{%
  \end{list}%
  \egroup
  \usebox{\mybox}%
}%
```

Here an complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\newenvironment{myenv}{%
 \setbox\mybox=\vbox\bgroup%
  \begin{list}{}{}%
}{%
  \end{list}%
  \egroup
  \usebox{\mybox}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you do have to use a `minipage`. Indeed `lrbox` is just the environment form of `\sbox` that is a companion to `\mbox` which wouldn't accept a list either: you can't directly typeset a paragraph in a `\mbox`. But

```
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\begin{enumerate}
\item a
\item b
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}
```

is correct code. In a `\mbox` or `\sbox` or `lrbox` TeX doesn't split lines.

Comment: Everything is fine except that I would like to have a `minipage` with variable width inside `lrbox`. Is it possible to do it, even if it's not the best? Thank you!

Comment: @manooooh What do you mean by “minipage with variable width"?

Comment: I mean the `{5cm}` of your code. The `5cm` has to be, let's say, `\mywidth`, where `\mywidth` changes.

Comment: @manooooh Use `\mywidth`: where's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that `\mywidth` is calculated when the `minipage` is drawn. For example, if we have `\begin{enumerate}\item Lonnnng\item Long` then `\mywidth` must be the width of the longest `\item` (`Lonnnng`).

Comment: @manooooh Oh! I think you want `varwidth`, then. Look for it in the site.

Answer (score 2):

The [`environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) allows for "storing" of content in a macro `\BODY`. Perhaps you might be interested in this implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\NewEnviron{myenv}{%
  \let\olditem\item%
  \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{\olditem[##1]\strut}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \begin{list}{}{}%
    \BODY%
  \end{list}%
  \end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}%
  \usebox{\mybox}%
}

\begin{document}
Some text.\strut

\begin{myenv}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\end{myenv}

Some text.
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Like with most box-implementations of `minipage`, you may have to play around with the baselineskip measures of `\prevdepth`. The above redefinition of `\item` (adding `\strut`) is a quick-fix. For more on this, see [How to keep a constant baselineskip when using minipages (or \parboxes)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/5764)