# How to align TikZ picture and text side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I want to add a `TikZ` picture beside a text block

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
\begin{tikzpicture}[color=white]
\node[fill=blue!70,rotate=90] at (0,0) {Vertical Text on Left};
\end{tikzpicture}
  \lipsum[2]
  \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

but with this structure, the TikZ` picture is inserted at the first line of text, instead of placing side by side.

[image]

One solution can be using packages like `wrapfig` to wrap the text around picture. Isn't there any easier solution to place `TikZ` figure beside text?

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: Y U NO love wrapfig?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar actually, I'm a big fan of `wrapfig`; just was curious if there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\parbox`, I just set the widths as a fraction of `\linewidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
\noindent\parbox[][][t]{.05\linewidth}{\begin{tikzpicture}[color=white]
\node[fill=blue!70,rotate=90] at (0,0) {Vertical Text on Left};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\parbox[][][t]{.95\linewidth}{
  \lipsum[2]
  \lipsum[3]
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See [How to keep a constant `\baselineskip` when using `minipages` (or `\parboxes`)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/5764) in terms of your vertical alignment. Perhaps all you need is a `\strut` in the last line of the paragraph preceding the `\parbox` (since it doesn't have any descenders).

Comment: Can the blue rectangle span  multiple pages?

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, here's a solution with `wrapfig`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{L}{.5cm}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{tikzpicture}[color=white]
\node[fill=blue!70,rotate=90,minimum width=9\baselineskip,align=center]
at (0,0) {Vertical Text on Left};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

(Author: Gonzalo Medina)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using the **minipage** environment. For contrast, \strut is used in one place and \bigkip in another to improve spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] \strut  
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.05\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[color=white]
    \node[fill=blue!70,rotate=90] at (0,0) {Vertical Text on Left};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage} \quad
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}
\bigskip\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]