# Increase spacing after minipage

Tags: spacing, equations, minipage

Hello i am using a line of code to draw 2 equations next to eachother using `\minipage{}`:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\small
\begin{equation}\label{e3}
\begin{split}
\frac{\mathrm d x'}{\mathrm d t} &= \frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t} - \frac{\mathrm d}    {\mathrm d t}(ut)\\
\frac{\mathrm d x'}{\mathrm d t} &= \frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t} - u \, \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}(t)\\
\frac{\mathrm d x'}{\mathrm d t} &= \frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t} - u \, \frac{\mathrm d t}{\mathrm d t}\\
v' &= v - u
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\small
\begin{equation}\label{e4}
\begin{split}
\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t} &= \frac{\mathrm d x'}{\mathrm d t} + \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}(ut)\\
\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t} &= \frac{\mathrm d x'}{\mathrm d t} + u \, \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}(t)\\
\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t} &= \frac{\mathrm d x'}{\mathrm d t} + u \, \frac{\mathrm d t}{\mathrm d t}\\
v &= v' + u
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
```

After compiling, using PDFLaTeX i get a resulting document which looks like this:
[image: too small spacing after minipage]

What can i do to increase vertical spacing after minipage, which is very small? I would also like to know, how can i take care of an annoying `\small` comand which i have to put inside every `\minipage{}` for my equations to look smaller? Can it be done in preamble?

Thank you.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below there's one possible solution; the key ideas were:

1. I used the solution given in [How to keep a constant baselineskip when using minipages (or \parboxes)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/3954) to guarantee spacing after the `minipage`s.
2. Before the minipages I used `\smallskip\nointerlinespacing`.
3. I defined a newenvironment `sminipage` (to apply `\small` inside `minipage`); the optional argument (set by default to `t`) controls the alignment of the `minipage` and the mandatory argument sets the width of the `minipage`.

I also made some other modifications to improve your code:

4. I removed the spurious blank space after the first `\end{minipage}`.
5. I defined a `\Pder` command to facilitate the writing of the partial derivatives.

The idea was to obtain (approximately) the same spacing around the equations inside the `minipage` as the one used for regular equations not inside a `minipage` (I added a `regular` equation environment at the end just for comparison purposes):

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
    
    \newcommand\Pder[2]{%
      \frac{\mathrm{d}#1}{\mathrm{d}#2}}
    
    \newenvironment{sminipage}[2][t]
      {\minipage[t]{#2}\small}
      {\endminipage}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \lipsum*[4]\par\smallskip\nointerlineskip
    \noindent\begin{sminipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{equation}\label{e3}
    \begin{split}
    \Pder{x'}{t} &= \Pder{x}{t} - \Pder{\phantom{x}}{t} (ut) \\
    \Pder{x'}{t} &= \Pder{x}{t} - u\,\Pder{\phantom{x}}{t} (t) \\
    \Pder{x'}{t} &= \Pder{x}{t} - u\,\Pder{t}{t} \\
    v' &= v - u
    \end{split}
    \end{equation}
    \end{sminipage}%
    \begin{sminipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{equation}\label{e4}
    \begin{split}
    \Pder{x}{t} &= \Pder{x'}{t} - \Pder{\phantom{x}}{t} (ut) \\
    \Pder{x}{t} &= \Pder{x'}{t} - u\,\Pder{\phantom{x}}{t} (t) \\
    \Pder{x}{t} &= \Pder{x'}{t} - u\,\Pder{t}{t} \\
    v &= v' + u
    \end{split}
    \end{equation}\null
    \par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}
    \end{sminipage}
    
    \prevdepth\tpd
    \noindent\lipsum[2]
    \begin{equation}
    a=b
    \end{equation}
    \lipsum[4]
    
    \end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

I defined now (as was requested in a comment) a new environment `eqmpage` which basically is a top aligned `minipage` with constant width of `\linewidth` which automates all the preparations mentioned above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newcommand\Pder[2]{%
  \frac{\mathrm{d}#1}{\mathrm{d}#2}}

\newenvironment{sminipage}[2][t]
  {\minipage[t]{#2}\small}
  {\endminipage}

\newenvironment{eqmpage}
  {\par\smallskip\nointerlineskip%
    \noindent\minipage[t]{\textwidth}}
  {\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}\endminipage\par\prevdepth\tpd}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[4]

\begin{eqmpage}
\begin{sminipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{equation}\label{e3}
\begin{split}
\Pder{x'}{t} &= \Pder{x}{t} - \Pder{\phantom{x}}{t} (ut) \\
\Pder{x'}{t} &= \Pder{x}{t} - u\,\Pder{\phantom{x}}{t} (t) \\
\Pder{x'}{t} &= \Pder{x}{t} - u\,\Pder{t}{t} \\
v' &= v - u
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{sminipage}%
\begin{sminipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{equation}\label{e4}
\begin{split}
\Pder{x}{t} &= \Pder{x'}{t} - \Pder{\phantom{x}}{t} (ut) \\
\Pder{x}{t} &= \Pder{x'}{t} - u\,\Pder{\phantom{x}}{t} (t) \\
\Pder{x}{t} &= \Pder{x'}{t} - u\,\Pder{t}{t} \\
v &= v' + u
\end{split}
\end{equation}\null
\end{sminipage}
\end{eqmpage}
\noindent\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: But this still has to have `\small` written in each minipage environment every time which is part of the problem of the OP. From what I understand, OP likes to have this thing taken care of in the preamble.

Comment: @hpesoj626 I've updated my answer.

Comment: Nice. I am trying to learn how to write packages and this example helps a lot. Thanks.

Comment: I love the idea about partial derivatives TY!

Comment: @71GA You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Is there a way to automate the inclusion of `\par\smallskip\nointerlineskip\noindent` at the beginning of minipages and `\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}` at the end?

Comment: @71GA it could be done, but then the result wouldn't be as expected since the modification would apply to every `sminipage` and in cases like yours, with two `sminipage`s side-by-side, the layout would be destroyed.

Comment: @71GA I updated with a new code defining a new environment to aotomate almost all the process; you still need to add `\null` manually.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the command `\bigskip` or `\medskip`.

If you will always use the same size, you can define

```
\def\bmp{\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}\small} 
\def\emp{\end{minipage}\smallskip}
```

for begin and end. Note the use of 48% for the width. You can change. You just need to put some `\hfill` between them.

```
\bmp \emp
\hfill
\bmp \emp
% this paragraph is important

text here....
```

Comment: For some reason this doesnt work. Makes absolutely no change to my document.

Comment: @71GA: Write `\bmp\begin{equation}...\end{equation}\emp` instead of `\begin{minipage}\begin{equation}...\end{equation}\end{minipage}`

Comment: @Sigur: Maybe editing the answer so that the modified MWE with your solution is shown will help.

Comment: I know. The problem is that you should use 2 consecutive, to produce the 2 minipage side by side. But the `\par` does not allow this. I am thinking about.

Answer (score 2):

I have upvoted @Sigur's answer. But you might also want to look at `genmpage` package. It adds additional options to your `minipage` environment and you can also write the options in the preamble.

To set your minipage text to small, put the following into your preamble:

```
\usepackage{genmpage}
\setkeys{GenMP}{resetfont,fsize=small,inner=s}
```

Then write your minipage environment as you usually do and you can use `\medskip` and `\bigskip` as suggested by @Sigur.