# Spacing problem while using itemize in minipage

Tags: spacing, itemize, minipage

I am using `itemize` in `minipage` and observe unexpected spacing among items.

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage[top=.5cm, bottom=2cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

This is first line.\newline
 \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\begin{itemize}[topsep=0ex]
 \item First Item
 \item Second Item
 \item Third Item
 \end{itemize}\end{minipage}  
 \newline This is second line.
 \end{document}
```

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This is very similar to [How to keep a constant `\baselineskip` when using `minipage`s (or `\parbox`es)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/5764) (possibly a duplicate).

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're using a minipage here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about this, but maybe the following is what you are looking for.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent This is first line.\\[\baselineskip]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item First Item
\item Second Item
\item Third Item
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\\[\baselineskip] This is second line.

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

***Update***

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

This is first line.\\[0.5\baselineskip]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item First Item
\item Second Item
\item Third Item
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\\[0.5\baselineskip] This is second line.

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: In my example, there is one newline before intemize. I want to reduce the space equal to 1 newline using topsep. But using baselineskip, space seems to be more.

Comment: "using baselineskip, space seems to be more": Then use, say, `\\[0.5\baselineskip]`. (I don't know if `0.5` is the correct factor; it's just a guess.)

Comment: my report is auto report so i cannot add \noindent. How can i avoid using this.

Comment: You can just delete it and then you are not using it... (I don't understand the question.)

Comment: If i use no indent, text before itemize get indented. Is there any way to not to indent without using \noindent

Comment: Arrrh, I see. See updated answer.