# Tikz itemize line spacing

Tags: tikz-pgf, itemize, line-spacing

I have a diagram in `tikz` where each node contains an itemized list.

```
\documentclass[11pt, authoryear, 3p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\tikzstyle{dataset} = [rectangle, draw, text width = 2in, minimum height=1in, ]
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, font=\scriptsize]
    % Place nodes
    \node [dataset] (tm) {Data 1 \begin{itemize}
            \item{\# Adults } \item{\# Children} \item{Income} 
            \item{Ethnicity}
          \end{itemize}};
    \node [dataset, right of=tm, node distance=3in] (dmv) {Data 2 \begin{itemize} \item{Data 2} \end{itemize}};
    % draw links
    \path [<->] (tm) edge node[above, sloped] {Address} (dmv);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Analysis dataset assembly.}
    \label{fig:dataset}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

The items are double-spaced, as the rest of the document. How can I set these nodes to be single-spaced? I have tried encasing the chunk in a `singlespaced` environment, and related questions (e.g., [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102574/spacing-problem-while-using-itemize-in-minipage)) don't seem to be precisely applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[11pt, authoryear, 3p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{tikz,enumitem,setspace,kantlipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}
\doublespacing
\kant[1]
\begin{figure}[htb]
\tikzset{dataset/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width = 2in, minimum height=1in}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, font={\scriptsize}]
    % Place nodes
    \node [dataset] (tm) {Data 1 
                            \begin{itemize}[itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,topsep=0pt]   %% this added.
                                \item{\# Adults } 
                                \item{\# Children} 
                                \item{Income}
                                \item{Ethnicity}
                            \end{itemize}\par};
    \node [dataset, right of=tm, node distance=3in] (dmv) {Data 2 
                            \begin{itemize}[itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,topsep=0pt] 
                                \item{Data 2} 
                            \end{itemize}\par};
    % draw links
    \path [<->] (tm) edge node[above, sloped] {Address} (dmv);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Analysis dataset assembly.}
    \label{fig:dataset}
\end{figure}
\kant[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You've beaten me for a minute. Anyway I think that with `topsep=5pt` it looks better :-)

Comment: @karlkoeller Thanks. :). I agree with `topsep`. But I want to leave it to the OP to adjust.