# Inconsistent spacing in itemize environment inside tikz node inside center environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, itemize, vertical-spacing, center

I have noticed inconsistent spacing when using itemized lists in a TikZ node when the tikzpicture is inside a centering environment.

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[align=left, text width=5cm] (0,0)
            {
                \textbf{Heading 1}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item{item 1}
                \end{itemize}
            };
            \node[align=left, text width=5cm] at (0,2)
            {
                \textbf{Heading 2}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item{item 2}
                \end{itemize}
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

and I get a result like this:

[image: example 1]

However, when I have the nodes in different order like this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[align=left, text width=5cm] at (0,2)
            {
                \textbf{Heading 2}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item{item 2}
                \end{itemize}
            };
            \node[align=left, text width=5cm] (0,0)
            {
                \textbf{Heading 1}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item{item 1}
                \end{itemize}
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

I get this output:

[image: example 2]

If I remove the centering environment around the tikzpicture, then both lists are rendered with similar spacing like this:

[image: example 3]

Why is this happening? Is this a bug? Is there a way that I can fix this?

I'm using TeX Live 2023 on Linux.

Comment: Don't know, lists inside nodes can be tricky. Loading the `enumitem` package and adding `[itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,topsep=0pt]` after each `\begin{itemize}` like in [A160457](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160457) seem to overwrite and egalize any weird things that are happening.