# Two labels on the same equation line

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, numbering

I would like to have a compact set of two equations on the same line, each one labeled, with both labels on the far right.
The code would be something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
We have
\begin{equation}
a = b \label{eqab} \quad \text{and} \quad c = d \label{eqcd}
\end{equation}
and equations \ref{eqab} and \ref{eqcd} are nice.
\end{document}
```

(the positions of the labels within the source line would not matter),
and would appear something like:

```
We have\vspace{3ex}

\hfill $a=b \quad \text{and} \quad c=d$ \hfill (1) and (2)\vspace{3ex}

and equations (1) and (2) are nice.
```

But putting two `\label` on the same line results in a `Package amsmath Error:

```
Multiple \label...` (the same for `\tag`).
```

Comment: Welcome to SE! The result is expected. It is not allowed to have two labels for one equation. From your example I see, that you  like to label two equation on one line. Why you not split them into two equations? How to do this has been showed many times on SE.

Comment: It's not `\label` that generates the equation number; so you'll get just one number and of course one `\label` suffices.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Two labeled equations on the same line with labels lining up vertically](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109579/5764)

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you looking for something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
We have:

    \noindent\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
a = b \label{eqab}
\end{equation} 
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}\centering
    and 
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
c = d \label{eqcd}
\end{equation}
    \end{minipage}\vskip1em

Equations \ref{eqab} and \ref{eqcd} are nice. The same is valid for the next two:

\begin{subequations}\label{eq:3}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
a = b \label{eq:3a}
\end{equation}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}\centering
    and
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
c = d \label{eq:3b}
\end{equation}
    \end{minipage}\vskip1em
\end{subequations}

which are  \ref{eq:3a} and \ref{eq:3b}.
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}
\begin{document}
We have

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXX}
\begin{equation}
    a = b \label{eqab}
\end{equation}
& \[ \text{and} \] &
\begin{equation}
    c = d \label{eqcd}
\end{equation}
\end{tabularx}

and equations \ref{eqab} and \ref{eqcd} are nice.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting that on a cell of `tabularx` we can use display `\[ \]`.

Comment: This does require the use of `\noindent\begin{tabularx}` if you're using `\textwidth` or `\linewidth`...

Comment: @Werner: yes, you are right

Comment: @Werner Why is that?

Comment: @A.Ellett: A `tabular` is like a block that starts a paragraph which is typically accompanied by a `\parindent`. Setting a block with a paragraph indent that has width `\textwidth` or `\linewidth` will be wider than the text block. Hence the use of `\noindent`.

Comment: @Werner Argh.  Something must have been wrong with my eyes last night.  I could have sworn that your comment had read something different.  I managed to completely misunderstand it.  I really should stop trying to think after a certain hour.  Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected, because it's not `\label` that generates the equation number.

If you really want two numbered equations on the same line, which I'd like to discourage, you can resort to minipages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
We have
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\textwidth}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{equation}
a = b \label{eqab}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill\hfill and\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\textwidth}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{equation}
c = d \label{eqcd}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
and equations \ref{eqab} and \ref{eqcd} are nice.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the label will always be *(1) and (2)* and if you will refer always both then you can make it a single label.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
We have
\begin{equation}
a=b \quad \text{and} \quad  c=d  \tag*{(1) and (2)}\label{1and2}
\end{equation}
and equations \ref{1and2} are nice.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Amsmath may specifically forbid more than one `\label` in an equation, but that doesn't mean one can't create another macro to perform the same task.  Note: this version is not compatible with hyperref.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\steplabel}[1]% #1 = label name
{\refstepcounter{equation}%
 \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newlabel{#1}{{\theequation}{\thepage}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
We have
\begin{equation}
a=b \quad \text{and} \quad c=d
\tag*{\steplabel{eqab}(\theequation) and \steplabel{eqcd}(\theequation)}
\end{equation}
and equations \eqref{eqab} and \eqref{eqcd} are nice.
\end{document}
```