# Vertical spacing around a parbox

Tags: spacing, boxes

Given this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newlength{\len}
\newcommand{\arrowed}[1]{%
  % draw an arrow, then a parbox that's exactly
  % the remaining width of the line
  \settowidth{\len}{$\rightarrow$}%
  \addtolength{\len}{-2\len}%
  \addtolength{\len}{\textwidth}%
  $\rightarrow$\parbox[t]{\len}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\arrowed{\lipsum[4]}
\lipsum[6]
\arrowed{But this is OK, since it's only one line.}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

It's double-spaced, except for immediately after the big parbox.  How do I fix that?

(I know there are other ways to achieve the same result as what I did here, but it's part of something else that is using the parbox in a list item label, and the problem that I'm having is that the spacing after the parbox is wrong if the contents are more than one line long.)

---

Edit:

Thanks for the suggestions.  Here is some more complete code that shows how
I'm using the parbox as part of a list item label, as mentioned.  I've tried to incorporate your suggestions: @Werner's suggestion (marked [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kar07.png) in the code) gives `You can't use \prevdepth in restricted horizontal mode`, while @Steven's suggestion (marked [2]) doesn't seem to have any effect.  I've tried a few variations of those but haven't had any luck.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace,lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\singlelipsum[1]{%
  \begingroup\let\lips@par\relax\csname lipsum@\@roman{#1}\endcsname
\endgroup }
\newlength{\argwidth}
\newcommand{\argparams}[1]{%
  \parbox[t]{\argwidth}{%
    \setstretch{1.5}%
    #1)%
    %\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}%  [1]
    %\strut%  [2]
  }%
  %\par\prevdepth\tpd%  [1]
  %\\\strut\ignorespaces%   [2]
}
\newcommand{\argfunc}[1]{\textbf{#1}(}
\newcommand{\argitem}[2]{
  \settowidth{\argwidth}{\argfunc{#1}}%
  \addtolength{\argwidth}{-2\argwidth}%
  \addtolength{\argwidth}{\textwidth}%
  \item[\argfunc{#1}\argparams{#2}]%
}
\newcommand{\argitemlabel}[1]{%
  \@tempdima\linewidth%
  \advance\@tempdima \leftmargin\makebox[\@tempdima][l]{#1}%
}
\newenvironment{arglist}{
  \begin{list}{}{%
      \setlength\labelwidth{\leftmargin}
      \setlength\labelsep{0pt}
      \setlength\rightmargin{0pt}
      \let\makelabel=\argitemlabel%
    }%
}{\end{list}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setstretch{2}
\begin{arglist}
\argitem{function}{args} body
\argitem{function}{\singlelipsum{4}} \singlelipsum{2}
\end{arglist}
\end{document}
```

[image: problem]

By the way, the approach I'm using is based on the `sphinx.sty` used by Sphinx-doc.  I think they don't have the problem because it's single spaced there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE (to reflect revised MWE):

The only thing I changed from your non-working MWE is that I added a `\relax\strut\ignorespaces` to the end of `\argitem`.  If I am understanding it properly, the `\item` had to be ended, because you had no text as part of the item (the `\parbox` was part of the `\item`'s optional argument).  So any `\strut` applied immediately afterward was set back on the top line of the paragraph (as part of the `\item`).  The `\relax` basically stopped the `\strut` from being gobbled by the `\item`.  I'm probably wrong in this explanation, but someone will correct me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace,lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\singlelipsum[1]{%
  \begingroup\let\lips@par\relax\csname lipsum@\@roman{#1}\endcsname
\endgroup }
\newlength{\argwidth}
\newcommand{\argparams}[1]{%
  \parbox[t]{\argwidth}{%
    \setstretch{1.5}%
    #1)%
    %\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}%  [1]
    %\strut%  [2]
  }%
  %\par\prevdepth\tpd%  [1]
  %\\\strut\ignorespaces%   [2]
}
\newcommand{\argfunc}[1]{\textbf{#1}(}
\newcommand{\argitem}[2]{
  \settowidth{\argwidth}{\argfunc{#1}}%
  \addtolength{\argwidth}{-2\argwidth}%
  \addtolength{\argwidth}{\textwidth}%
  \item[\argfunc{#1}\argparams{#2}]\relax\strut\ignorespaces%
}
\newcommand{\argitemlabel}[1]{%
  \@tempdima\linewidth%
  \advance\@tempdima \leftmargin\makebox[\@tempdima][l]{#1}%
}
\newenvironment{arglist}{
  \begin{list}{}{%
      \setlength\labelwidth{\leftmargin}
      \setlength\labelsep{0pt}
      \setlength\rightmargin{0pt}
      \let\makelabel=\argitemlabel%
    }%
}{\end{list}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setstretch{2}
\begin{arglist}
\argitem{function}{args} body
\argitem{function}{\singlelipsum{4}} \singlelipsum{2}
\end{arglist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

ORIGINAL SOLUTION (for original MWE):

I see two things going on.  The first, concerning the bottom of a `\parbox` can be resolved with judicious use of `\strut`s.

The second issue relates to the `\lipsum[]` material commonly used in MWEs.  When lipsum paragraphs are output, they contain more than text.  They contain paragraph formatting, in the form of `\par`s and stuff like that.  Typically, if one were typing text as an argument for `\arrowed`, one would not end on a `\par`. And so, it would be better to get lipsum to output just the text of a paragraph, without the ending `\par` and such.

The author of `lipsum` told me how to do that:

```
\newcommand\singlelipsum[1]{%
  \begingroup\let\lips@par\relax\csname lipsum@\@roman{#1}\endcsname
\endgroup }
```

And so, with the combination of `\strut` and `\singlelipsum` (which gives just the text of a single lipsum paragraph), one can fix the problem with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\singlelipsum[1]{%
  \begingroup\let\lips@par\relax\csname lipsum@\@roman{#1}\endcsname
\endgroup }
\makeatother
\newlength{\len}
\newcommand{\arrowed}[1]{%
  % draw an arrow, then a parbox that's exactly
  % the remaining width of the line
  \settowidth{\len}{$\rightarrow$}%
  \addtolength{\len}{-2\len}%
  \addtolength{\len}{\textwidth}%
  $\rightarrow$\parbox[t]{\len}{#1\strut}\\\strut\ignorespaces%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\arrowed{\singlelipsum{4}}
\lipsum[6]
\arrowed{But this is OK, since it's only one line.}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Steven, I didn't know that about lipsum.  Unfortunately the struts don't seem to be doing it for me -- I've edited the question with a more complete example that shows how I'm using the parbox inside a list label.

Comment: @JimParis  I've revised answer to fix your new MWE (I think).

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for the update.  That does the trick!

Answer (score 3):

Your definition of `\arrowed` should look like this:

```
\newcommand{\arrowed}[1]{%
  % draw an arrow, then a parbox that's exactly
  % the remaining width of the line
  \settowidth{\len}{$\rightarrow$}%
  \addtolength{\len}{-2\len}%
  \addtolength{\len}{\textwidth}%
  $\rightarrow$\parbox[t]{\len}{#1\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}}%
  \par\prevdepth\tpd%
}
```

This restores the box depth after its been set, as suggested in [How to keep a constant `\baselineskip` when using `minipage`s (or `\parbox`es)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/5764).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,setspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newlength{\len}
\newcommand{\arrowed}[1]{%
  % draw an arrow, then a parbox that's exactly
  % the remaining width of the line
  \settowidth{\len}{$\rightarrow$}%
  \addtolength{\len}{-2\len}%
  \addtolength{\len}{\textwidth}%
  $\rightarrow$\parbox[t]{\len}{#1\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}}%
  \par\prevdepth\tpd%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\arrowed{\lipsum[4]}
\lipsum[6]
\arrowed{But this is OK, since it's only one line.}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

---

However... it might be far better to use a list to set the item, since `\parbox`es (like `minipage`s) are not breakable across the page boundary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,setspace,enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,setspace,enumitem}
\setstretch{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newlength{\len}
\newcommand{\arrowed}[1]{%
  \begin{itemize}[nosep]\item[{\makebox[2em][r]{$\rightarrow$}}]#1\end{itemize}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\arrowed{\lipsum[4]}
\lipsum[6]
\arrowed{But this is OK, since it's only one line.}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) provides the `nosep` option that removes all vertical gaps between the list, items and surrounding content.

Comment: Thanks @Werner.  Makes sense, but unfortunately setting the depth doesn't work inside the list label that I'm trying to use.  Please see my edits to the question with a more complete example.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `paralist` package, and define them as list items.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{paralist}
\setstretch{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newenvironment{arrowed}{
  \begin{compactitem}[$\rightarrow$]
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}{
  \end{compactitem}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{arrowed}
\item \lipsum[4]
\item \lipsum[4]
\item \lipsum[6]
\end{arrowed}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{arrowed}
\item  This is also OK, since it's only one line.
\end{arrowed}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

I changed your sharelatex doc to reflex these changes.

[image: Render from sharelatex]

Comment: Thanks @El.  This falls under the "other ways to achieve the same result" that I mentioned, and is unfortunately not applicable to my more complete example.  Still very useful, though.