# Align columns, last vertical line bug and add row height

Tags: tabularx

This is my table:

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52838329/tabular.png]

I have a few problems:

1. I want both columns to take each 50% of the page width (excl margin), but the second column's text needs to be aligned right.
2. The last vertical line is not correctly placed
3. The first and last row need to be a bit higher so the text fits better.

   ```
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{0.5\textwidth}|p{0.5\textwidth}|}
   \hline
   \textbf{{\Large Activa}} & \textbf{{\Large Passiva}}\\ \hline
   \hline 
   \textbf{Aanwendingsvormen} van het vermogen & \textbf{Vermogensbronnen}\\

   \begin{itemize}
   \item Bezittingen
   \item Vorderingen
   \end{itemize}
   &
   \begin{itemize}
   \item Eigen vermogen
   \item Vreemd vermogen
   \end{itemize}\\

   \textbf{Ondernemingsmiddelen} & \textbf{Ondernemingsbronnen}\\
   Welke middelen heeft de onderneming om haar activiteit te ontwikkelen? & Hoe financiert de onderneming de ondernemingsmiddelen.\\
   \hline \hline
   \textbf{{\Large Vermogen} van de onderneming} & \textbf{{\Large Vermogen} van de onderneming}\\\hline
   \end{tabularx}
   ```

I didn't find anything on this, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some things you need to do:

- Use `\textbf{\Large\strut ...}` in *one* of the header entries. This inserts a vertical strut of the appropriate size to obtain better spacing. There's also more ideas in terms of vertical adjustment of table entries in [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764).
- Include the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) in your preamble

  ```
  \usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
  ```

  and use a `tabularx` column specification of the form

  ```
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\raggedright}X|>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X|}
  % ...
  \end{tabularx}
  ```

  This inserts `\raggedright` [`\raggedleft`] in the first [second] column so items should be left- [right-]aligned. Note that lists do not conform to this adjustment. To that end, I've used [`varwidth`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth)'s `varwidth` environment for capturing the list in a box of natural width (if it is smaller than the width of the column, or `\linewidth`).
- Also, use `\noindent` before `tabularx`:

  ```
  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{...}
  %...
  \end{tabularx}
  ```

  otherwise your `tabularx` position won't sit flush with the margins.

Here is a complete MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,varwidth}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{array,tabularx,varwidth}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\raggedright}X|>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X|}
  \hline
  \textbf{{\Large\strut Activa}} & \textbf{{\Large Passiva}} \\
  \hline\hline 
  \textbf{Aanwendingsvormen} van het vermogen & \textbf{Vermogensbronnen} \\[1.5\normalbaselineskip]
  \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Bezittingen
      \item Vorderingen
    \end{itemize}
  \end{varwidth} &
  \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Eigen vermogen
      \item Vreemd vermogen
    \end{itemize}
  \end{varwidth} \\[2\normalbaselineskip]
  \textbf{Ondernemingsmiddelen} & \textbf{Ondernemingsbronnen} \\
  Welke middelen heeft de onderneming om haar activiteit te ontwikkelen? & 
  Hoe financiert de onderneming de ondernemingsmiddelen.\\
  \hline\hline
  \textbf{{\Large\strut Vermogen} van de onderneming} & 
  \textbf{{\Large Vermogen} van de onderneming} \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

<sub>Unknown (or incorrect) hyphenation patterns could also be problematic when it comes to line-breaking (not the case/issue here). If need be, you can manually force a different hyphenation using a `blah\-blah\-blah` approach.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. Only the list is indeed still left. I tried flushright, but that didn't help either. What else can I do?

Comment: @Aaron: I've adapted the solution a bit, mainly with the addition of `varwidth` to align the `itemize`. It's one option. Check the [revision history](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/129627/revisions) for a complete picture of the changes. Since you're using a `tabularx` environment for "parallel typesetting", the vertical adjustments around the `itemize` is natural. The problems around these vertical adjustments stem from the boxing; for more on this discussion, see [How to keep a constant `\baselineskip` when using `minipage`s (or `\parbox`es)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/5764).

Comment: I just did a complete install of texlive (upgrade), but varwidth is still not installed? How can install this? (Ubuntu)

Comment: @Aaron: `sudo tlmgr install varwidth`? Perhaps see [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1) or [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/5764)