# \vfill and vertical space

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, environments

In a two-column document, I would like some text to be positioned at the bottom right of the right column. The text is inside `tabular` and `flushright`. An MWE is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]
\vfill
\begin{flushright}
  \begin{tabular}[b]{p{3cm} r}
    some text & 0
  \end{tabular}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

However, there is some vertical space below (see image) which I would like to remove so the part "some text 0" fully aligns with the left column at the bottom.

I believe I would need to edit the spacing for both `flushright` and `tabular` in this instance but don't know how (other than just manually adding a negative space via `\vspace{-1.5em}`). Help appreciated!

---

**EDIT:** To explain why I use/need the `tabular`, here is working example less minimal but more similar to my needs. It already uses some of the answers below.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]
\vspace*{\fill}

\noindent
\makebox[\linewidth][r]{
  \begin{tabular}[b]{ b{3cm} r@{}}
  some long, line-wrapped text &
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{img}
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

But there still seems to be some small space below the box.

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\vspace*{\fill}


\noindent
\makebox[\linewidth][r]{some text \quad 0}



\end{document}
```

Note you want `\vspace*` not `\vfill` or the space would be discarded if the column break happened at that point.

Comment: My MWE might be a little too simplistic. Since I have longer (line-wrapped) text and an image in the `tabular`, I can't just replace it by `{some text \quad 0}`. Your solution does a great job, but if I place the `tabular` from above where you have `{some text \quad 0}` I still have a (small) space below. Could I remove this, too? Thanks!

Comment: you can replace the `\noindent\makebox{}` by `\raggedleft text text ... ...` or include a tabular at that point, the baselines may not quite line up with the first column as latex doesn't really try to do that.

Comment: I'm sorry if I don't quite get it, but if I use `tabular` inside the `makebox` (since `\raggedleft` doesn't work with the combination of line-wrapped text and an image, see my update above) the bottom still does not match (though it's a lot better). Are you saying it just won't work?

Comment: ah well It's probably put by the depth of a `g` (you see the line rise up in my original one line example if you add a g. You could hide hide the depth of the box \raisebox{0pt}[0pt]{...} would do it but if the natural column break put a descender at the end of the first column you'd be wrong again, that could be fixed but would require opening up latex internals (perhaps at the weekend, not now:-)

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you box stuff, baselines tend to get messy (see [How to keep a constant `\baselineskip` when using `minipage`s (or `\parbox`es)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/5764)). You could do some manual jigging of the baseline if you have descenders (like in the example below, `\smash{<stuff>}` removed the vertical height/depth of `<stuff>`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]
\vspace*{\fill}

\noindent
\makebox[\linewidth][r]{%
  \parbox[b]{3cm}{some long, line-\smash{wrapped} text}\quad%
  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}%
}
\end{document}
```

Surely not ideal, but perhaps it'll work in your situation.