# An equation of text on multiple lines

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I am trying to do something like the following:

[image]

Does anyone have an example of a technique on how to do this? It needs to be centered in the middle of the paper like the `$$ $$` environment and it would be a bonus if it can be labelled and referred to later on.

Comment: A “real world” example might help: how to manage the text that stands for the usual variables depends on its nature; is it long? Is it just two lines to be centered with respect to each other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the text inside a regular `\parbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\textbox}[3][c]{\parbox[#1]{#2}{\strut#3\strut}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \left\{\textbox{2cm}{Here is some regular text}\right\} =
    \left\{\textbox{2cm}{Here is some more regular text}\right\} +
    \left\{\textbox{3cm}{This is the last piece of text in the equation}\right\} \label{eqn:myeqn}
\end{equation}
See~(\ref{eqn:myeqn}).
\end{document}
```

`\parbox[<valign>]{<width>}{<stuff>}` sets `<stuff>` in a `par`agraph `box` of width `<width>` and aligned vertically according to `<valign>` (`t`op, `c`entered or `b`ottom). The use of `\strut`s at the start/end tries to rectify the spacing problem associated with boxing. As reference, see [How to keep a constant `\baselineskip` when using `minipage`s (or `\parbox`es)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/5764).

The idea behind using a macro called `\textbox` is an attempt to promote typesetting [consistency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764).

Comment: Thank you, perfect. If you can spare me some google, what is a "parbox"

Comment: @masfenix: I've added some explanation.

Comment: the first line of the last element is terribly spacy.  i think it would look better if the text in the boxes were ragged right or centered. (`raggwed2e` might be better than "ordinary" ragged right.)