# Uneven spacing between parbox

Tags: spacing, boxes

I have uneven vertical space between two parboxes and between a parbox and beginning of a new text paragraph. How to fix these? Here is a minimum working example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
Hello 0!!

\parbox[t]{\textwidth-2.5cm}{\noindent{\textsc{\bfseries{First Document Management System}:} This is a long description of Document Management System. Very long indeed to fill two lines.}}\parbox[t]{2.5cm}{\hfill{2005-2009}}

\parbox[t]{\textwidth-2.5cm}{\noindent{\textsc{\bfseries{Second Document Management System}:} This is a long description of Document Management System. Very long indeed to fill two lines.}}\parbox[t]{2.5cm}{\hfill{2009-Present}}

\parbox[t]{\textwidth-2.5cm}{\noindent{\textsc{\bfseries{Last Document Management System}:} This is a long description of Document Management System. Very long indeed to fill two lines.}}\parbox[t]{2.5cm}{\hfill{2009-Present}}

Hello 1!!

Hello 2!!

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want a similar gap such as the gap between Hello 1 and Hello 2. between two paraboxes and similar gap between last parbox and Hello 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should write all your `\parbox`es using

```
\parbox[.]{<len>}{\strut ... \strut}
```

in order to obtain the appropriate line-height - `\strut` ensures this.

However, your input can be presented a little differently using the following [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) approach and it's far easier to manage:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,array}
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\begin{document}
Hello 0!!\strut

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}@{}}
  \highlight{First Document Management System}:
  This is a long description of Document Management System. Very long indeed to fill two lines. &
  2005--2009 \\
  \highlight{Second Document Management System}: This is a long description of Document Management System. 
  Very long indeed to fill two lines. &
  2009--Present \\
  \highlight{Last Document Management System}: This is a long description of Document Management System. 
  Very long indeed to fill two lines. &
  2009--Present
\end{tabularx}

Hello 1!!

Hello 2!!

\end{document}
```

Note that the `tabularx` is not breakable across the page boundary.

Comment: you really also need a `\strut` to end the "Hello0!!` line above the `tabularx`.  (the documentation says there used to be an optional argument `[t]` that would have taken care of this, but it's no longer available.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Correct. I didn't even look outside of the `tabularx` construction once I started - had blinders on, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the trick you can find in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34982/) to [How to keep a constant baselineskip when using minipages (or \parboxes)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34971/how-to-keep-a-constant-baselineskip-when-using-minipages-or-parboxes)

You should also avoid repetitive explicit markup, by defining an environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc,xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{entry}{O{2.5cm}mm}
 {\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth-#1}
  \textsc{#3:} \ignorespaces}
 {\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}% the trick in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34982/
  \end{minipage}%
  \makebox[#1][r]{#2}\par
  \prevdepth\tpd}

\begin{document}
Hello!!

\begin{entry}{2005-2009}{First Document Management System}
This is a long description of Document Management System. Very long 
indeed to fill two lines.
\end{entry}

\begin{entry}{2009-Present}{Second Document Management System}
This is a long description of Document Management System. Very long 
indeed to fill two lines.
\end{entry}

\begin{entry}{2009-Present}{Last Document Management System}
This is a long description of Document Management System. Very long 
indeed to fill two lines.
\end{entry}

Hello 1!!

Hello 2!!

\end{document}
```

[image]