# Section heading with shaded background spanning \textwidth, with uniform baseline

Tags: parbox, colorbox, baseline

I’m trying to adapt one of the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40034) so that only the section text, and not the section number, has a coloured background. Unfortunately the use of `\parbox` seems to result in a non-uniform baseline (if you look closely, you can see that “This is the title” is rendered on a lower baseline than “0.1”):

[image]

What I’m after is something like the text underneath, but with the shading extending all the way to the right. The use of `\parbox` seems to be the problem (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216388) for example) but I don’t know how to make the shading work otherwise.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
  {\sffamily\large}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\colorsection}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}

\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
  \thesection\ \colorbox{blue!20}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\section{This is the title}
\noindent{\sffamily\large 0.1 \colorbox{blue!20}{This is the title}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not good since the blue box is too wide. Load `\usepackage{showframe}` to see.

Comment: You have to use `\parbox[t]` (otherwise test with a very long section title). But you still have to take care of box width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, don't use `titlesec` with `scrbook`. They are incompatible and support for `titlesec` will be dropped in a near future.

The trick to use is `\parbox[t]`. You also have to take care of the space for the section number.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
  {\sffamily\large}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\colorsection}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}

\newlength{\secnumberwd}

\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
  \settowidth\secnumberwd{\thesection\ }%
  \thesection\ \colorbox{blue!20}{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-\secnumberwd}{#1}}% 
}

\begin{document}

\section{This is the title}

\noindent{\sffamily\large 0.1 \colorbox{blue!20}{This is the title}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Grr. I didn’t spot that the other question used `scrbook`, which I’m not interested in. It would have been better to use `article` for the MWE, but I won’t change it now. Thanks for the answer - I hadn’t spotted the need for `-\secnumberwd` but that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion using `scrbook` without package `titlesec`, because `titlesec` should not be used with a KOMA-Script class. You can redefine `\sectionlinesformat`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
%\providecommand*{\Ifstr}{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif

\usepackage{xcolor}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=\baselineskip,
  afterskip=\baselineskip,
  afterindent=false,
  font=\large\mdseries
]{section}
\renewcommand*\sectionformat{\thesection\ }
\colorlet{sectionbgcolor}{blue!20}

\newcommand*\originalsectionlinesformat{}
\let\originalsectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat
\renewcommand*\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{section}
    {\colorsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}% for level section
    {\originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}% original definition for other levels using style=section
}

\newlength{\secnumberwd}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\colorsectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \settowidth\secnumberwd{\hskip #2#3}%
  \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{%
    \colorbox{#1bgcolor}{%
      \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-\secnumberwd}{#4}%
  }}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{This is the title}
{\sffamily\large 0.1 \colorbox{blue!20}{This is the title}\par}
\addsec{Unnumbered section}
\end{document}
```

[image]