# Length space on parbox

Tags: boxes

I am trying to build a table on LaTeX with Parbox. I have found how to do with `\parbox`. However, the length between rows makes the text so pack. Do you know how to increase the length?

I have tried with `\parbox[15em]{108pt}{\raggedright` according to: `\parbox[position][height][inner-pos]{width}{text}` included on `herbert.the-little-red-haired-girl.org/html/latex2e/…` However, I don't get the space between the rows :(

My table code  is given below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

{\raggedright
\vspace{3pt} \noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{108pt}|p{223pt}|p{52pt}|}
\hline
\parbox{108pt}{\raggedright 
Attribute
} & \parbox{223pt}{\raggedright 
Description
} & \parbox{52pt}{\raggedright 
Characteristic
} \\
\hline
\parbox{108pt}{\raggedright 
Language
} & \parbox{223pt}{\raggedright
Programming language of the source code.
} & \parbox{52pt}{\raggedright \multirow{5}{*}{
Project
}} \\
\cline{1-3}
\parbox{108pt}{\raggedright 
Team\_size
} & \parbox[70em]{223pt}{\raggedright
Number of active core team members during the last 3 months prior to creation.
} &  \\
\cline{1-3} 
\parbox[15em]{108pt}{\raggedright 
Perc\_external\_contribs
} & \parbox{223pt}{\raggedright 
Ratio of commits from external contributors over core team members in the last 3 months prior to creation of pull request.
} &  \\
\cline{1-2} 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{2pt}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: One problem here is that a `parbox` (and `minipage`) loses its baseline skips for the first/last lines, as discussed in [How to keep a constant baseline skip when using `minipage`s (or `\parbox`es)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/5764) (possible duplicate). Of course, there are other problems with your setup, but that doesn't seem to be relevant to the actual question, since you only pose the problem with the spacing (related to the `\parbox` baseline skip).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `p` column type, there is no need for all those `\parbox`es. The `\raggedright` can be inserted in to the column defintion making the code tidy. I hace used `\RaggedRight` from `ragged2e` package to enable hyphenation. And at last `\cline{1-3}` has been changed to `\cline{1-2}`. And the width of columns have been specified as a fraction of line width instead of hard coded values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

{\raggedright
\vspace{3pt} \noindent
\begin{tabular}{|>{\RaggedRight}p{0.275\linewidth}|>{\RaggedRight}p{0.55\linewidth}|
>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{0.18\linewidth}|}
\hline
Attribute
 &
Description
 &
Characteristic
 \\
\hline
Language
 &
Programming language of the source code.
 & \multirow{5}{*}{
Project
} \\
\cline{1-2}

Team\_size
 &
Number of active core team members during the last 3 months prior to creation.
 &  \\
\cline{1-2}
Perc\_external\_contribs
 &
Ratio of commits from external contributors over core team members in the last 3 months prior to creation of pull request.
 &  \\
\cline{1-2}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{2pt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have already added the changes to the complete table