# Minipage with tabular inside ignores vertical alignment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, minipage

I am trying to align a `minipage` that has a list inside. Using a `tabular` environment for the list results in the minipage ignoring the `[t]` option (or any other, as far as I can tell). On the other hand, using a `description` environment yields the correct result, but I don't like how it aligns the `item[]`s with different length, and so would prefer using the tabular.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \textbf{One set of notes.}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{ }l@{}}
            Note 1: & This is the first note \\
            Note 2: & This is the second note \\
            Note 3: & This is the third note \\
            Note 4: & This is the fourth note \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}

    \textbf{Another set of notes.}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \begin{description}
            \item[Note 1:] This is the first note \\
            \item[Note 2:] This is the second note \\
            \item[Note 3:] This is the third note \\
            \item[Note 4:] This is the fourth note \\
        \end{description}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The result is shown in the image at the bottom.

Is there a way of using a `tabular` inside a `minipage` that acknowledges the vertical alignment?

[image: Ignoring alignment option]

Comment: You want `\begin{tabular}[t]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[t]`op alignment of the `minipage` aligns it's content at the top of the anchor point of the `minipage` interior. Since the `minipage` interior has an anchor point in the middle - given by the `tabular` block, the `minipage` "top" results in the (vertical) middle of the block.

To avoid this, specify the `tabular` anchor point as being `[t]`op as well:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textbf{One set of notes.}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{ }l@{}}
    Note 1: & This is the first note \\
    Note 2: & This is the second note \\
    Note 3: & This is the third note \\
    Note 4: & This is the fourth note \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\textbf{Another set of notes.}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
  \begin{description}
    \item[Note 1:] This is the first note \\
    \item[Note 2:] This is the second note \\
    \item[Note 3:] This is the third note \\
    \item[Note 4:] This is the fourth note \\
  \end{description}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Since there are [known problems with baseline settings in `minipage`/`\parbox` boxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/5764), you may be better off setting the entire `minipage`-`tabular` combination in a nested `tabular`:

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{0.5\linewidth}@{}}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{@{}r@{ }X@{}}
    Note 1: & This is the first note \\
    Note 2: & This is the second note \\
    Note 3: & This is the third note \\
    Note 4: & This is the fourth note \\
  \end{tabularx}
\end{tabular}
```

I've inserted a [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) inner to allow for a fixed-width `0.5\linewidth` structure.