# How to keep a constant baselineskip when using minipages in tables?

Tags: minipage, line-spacing

Following up this question:

[How to keep a constant baselineskip when using minipages (or \parboxes)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34971/how-to-keep-a-constant-baselineskip-when-using-minipages-or-parboxes)

The answers to the question suggest that `\strut` is not perfect to space minipages well with regard to the following line. They suggest a combination of the commands `\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}` (within the minipage) and `\prevdepth\tpd` (outside the minipage).

However, the suggested solution is not working in tables, because `\prevdepth\tpd` needs to be written in a separate spaced-out line to work:

```
...
\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}   
\end{minipage}

\prevdepth\tpd
...
```

The command would not allow me to use `\\` instead of an empty line. However, the `tabular`-environment needs the `\\` to separate the lines.

I tried

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.2 \linewidth}p{0.2 \linewidth}}
    lipsum & %
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
        lipsum\\lipsum
        \par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth} 
    \end{minipage}\par
    \prevdepth\tpd 
    lipsum & lipsum
\end{tabular}
```

and similar things. I either get a compilation error from `\prevdepth\tpd` or from the `tabular`'s missing `\\`. If I use an empty line and `\\`, I get an extra unwanted line break.

Is there a way to get this solution to work?

Edit: As requested, a full example

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.2 \linewidth}p{0.2 \linewidth}}
lipsum & %
 \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}lipsum\\libsum
 \end{minipage}\\ 
lipsum & lipsum
\end{tabular}
lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: Output without fix]

Using the spacing command as suggested above I get this:
[image: Output with fix]

This close to the desired output, but comes at the cost of a compilation error (because of the missing line separator `\\` in the table).

Comment: Can you add a full example (without the settings related to `\prevdepth`), just to see what's the alignment you want to fix?

Comment: It's not clear the reason for wanting a minipage, as already a `p` column makes it.

Comment: The reason for the minipage is the need for an `itemize` inside the table, for which you need the minipage. The itemize is not needed to show the problem, so I did not include it in the example.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a minipage in order to have an `itemize` or `enumerate` in a `p` column: just issue `\@minipagetrue` inside it.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\@minipagetrue}p{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|P{0.2 \linewidth}|P{0.2 \linewidth}|}
\hline
lipsum & 
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\end{itemize}
lipsum \\
\hline
lipsum & lipsum\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|P{0.2 \linewidth}|P{0.2 \linewidth}|}
\hline
lipsum & 
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item A
\item B
\end{itemize}
lipsum \\
\hline
lipsum & lipsum\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I added the rules just for better showing the various cells, not because I endorse their usage.

[image]

Comment: This is pretty nice, I did not know that. I only found the version including a minipage on the internet. However, if I want to start a new line after the `itemize` I also have and extra line between the `itemize` and the next line and I also have to shift it up by one line using the `\\[-bst]` trick from above. Never the less it saves my quite a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a rather sloggish answer to my question. I hope there will be a better one, but it works.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newlength{\bls}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\bls}{\baselineskip}
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.2 \linewidth}p{0.2 \linewidth}}
    lipsum & %
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
        lipsum\\lipsum
        \par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth} 
    \end{minipage}

    \prevdepth\tpd\\[\-bls]
    lipsum & lipsum
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

As mentioned above I can get the code to work on the cost of gaining an extra line. I can then shift the text upwards one line by using `\\[-\bsl]`.
For some reason it would not let me use `\\[-\baselineskip]` directly to shift the text upwards while I can use `\\[\baselineskip]`to shift the text one line downwards.  Instead I need to define a new length outside the tabular. Only then both up and down shifting work as they should. (My latex skills are not good enough to know why this is the case.)