# longtable (and xltabular), enumerated list in cells and \@minipagetrue

Tags: spacing, longtable, enumerate, itemize, xltabular

From [egreg answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/242145/9632) to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/242121/9632), I have learned to redirect `\@minipagetrue` into table cells to get rid of the extra space above `enumerate`-environments (and `itemize` and `description`). However, if I try this trick in a `longtable`, it will not work. I can set the enumerate in a `\parbox`, but then I do not need the redirection. Here is an MWE (taken from the referred answer and modified).

Is this a feature, a bug or is it me misunderstanding (i.e. user error)?

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array, longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\@minipagetrue}p{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|P{0.2 \linewidth}|P{0.2 \linewidth}|}
\hline
lipsum & 
\begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=*]
\item A
\item B
\end{itemize}
lipsum \\
\hline
lipsum & lipsum\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{longtable}[l]{|P{0.2 \linewidth}|P{0.2 \linewidth}|}
\hline
lipsum & 
\begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=*]
\item A
\item B
\end{itemize}
lipsum \\
\hline
lipsum & 
\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=*]
\item A
\item B
\end{itemize}}
lipsum \\
\hline
lipsum & lipsum\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The same problem is with `xltabular` (which also use `longtable`) at `p` or `X` column type.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you. I changed the heading and tagging to include xltabular.

Comment: It seems that  this is bug in `longtable`. Meanwhile i tested `\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\minipage{\hsize}\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}<{\endminipage}}`. It reduce  vertical space before `itemize` for about `1/3 \baselineskip` . Interestingly ...

Comment: @Zarko It is the same effect you get when you redirect @minipagetrue into the column. Since minipage need a width, this is a hassle in LaTeX standard tabulars which do not reset `\hsize`. In longtable, it is a good alternative to define a special purpose column, since `\hsize` contains the column width. You should set the `[t]` option in the minipage, to have same vertical alignment as the content of other cells in the row.

Comment: @Zarko Since your comments is the only answer I get, I suggest that you you write an answer,indicating the your comment is an an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem noted in your question partly can be solved with following definition of column type:

```
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\minipage{\hsize}\arraybackslash}p{#1}<{\endminipage}}
```

Interestingly is, that above column type definition doesn't work if you remove `\arraybackslash` from it. For test try the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\minipage{\hsize}\arraybackslash}p{#1}<{\endminipage}}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\@minipagetrue}p{#1}} %this not work as expected :-(
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begingroup
    \centering
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep, leftmargin=*}
\begin{tabular}{|P{0.2\linewidth}|P{0.2\linewidth}|}
    \hline
lipsum  &   \begin{itemize}
        \item A
        \item B
            \end{itemize}
            lipsum \\
    \hline
lipsum  &   lipsum\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\medskip
\begin{longtable}{|P{0.2\linewidth}|P{0.2\linewidth}|}
    \hline
lipsum  &   \begin{itemize}
        \item A
        \item B
            \end{itemize}
            lipsum \\
    \hline
lipsum  &   lipsum\\
    \hline
    \end{longtable}

\medskip
\begin{longtable}{|M{0.2\linewidth}|M{0.2\linewidth}|}
    \hline
lipsum  &   \begin{itemize}
        \item A
        \item B
            \end{itemize}
            lipsum \\
    \hline
lipsum  &   lipsum\\
    \hline
    \end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

which gives the following result:

[image]