# Vertical alignment in new macro

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I have the following macro:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[4]{
\begin{tabbing}
    \hspace{2cm} \= \kill
    \textbf{#1} \>  {#3} \\
    \textbf{#2} \>      
            \begin{minipage}{\smallertextwidth}
                \vspace{1mm}
                \textbf{label:} #4
            \end{minipage}
        \end{tabbing}
```

}

what happens is that the string given by `\textbf{#2}` is vertically aligned to the middle of the `minipage` on its side, while I'd like to have it aligned to the top of the `minipage`. How can achieve such an alignment?

Comment: Why do you need a `minipage`? Will the text in `#4` span multiple lines (like a paragraph)?

Comment: I just modified an environment I found in a document template. The minipage is needed because in the tabbing environment lines are not broken: a long sentence would be on a single line causing overfull hbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `tabbing` can reveal useful at times, it is not for this application, where a simpler `tabular` environment suffices:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newlength{\mycommandwidth}
\setlength{\mycommandwidth}{2cm}% or what you prefer as default

\newcommand{\mycommand}[5][\mycommandwidth]{% <--- don't forget it
  \par\noindent
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l p{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\tabcolsep-#1} @{}}
    \makebox[#1][l]{\bfseries #2} & #4 \\
    \makebox[#1][l]{\bfseries #3} & \textbf{label:} #5
  \end{tabular}%
  \par
}

\begin{document}

\mycommand{One}{Two}{Three}{Four}

\mycommand[1cm]{One}{Two}{Three}{Four}

\mycommand{One}{Two}{\lipsum[2]}{\lipsum[2]}

\mycommand[1cm]{One}{Two}{\lipsum[2]}{\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be a to use a `tabular`-like construction. And, to avoid using arbitrary lengths, you can leave the length-calculations up to LaTeX when using [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[4]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\bfseries\arraybackslash}p{2cm} X @{}}
    #1 & #3 \\
    #2 & \textbf{label:} #4
  \end{tabularx}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\mycommand{One}{Two}{Three}{Four}

\noindent
\mycommand{One}{Two}{\lipsum[3]}{\lipsum[4]}

\end{document}
```

The `p`- and `X`-columns have a default `t`op-alignment with the surrounding row entries.

The choice of using `tabularx` (or something `tabular`) above a `minipage` stems from the typical problem of baseline alignment. It's just easier/more convenient when using a table. See How to keep a constant baseline skip when using `minipage`s (or `\parbox`es)?]([How to keep a constant baselineskip when using minipages (or \parboxes)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/5764))

Note that the above construction will not break across the page boundary. That was also the case with your `minipage` construction, so I doubt it would be a problem in your use case