# Spacing after \vtop

Tags: spacing, boxes, line-spacing, plain-tex, columns

There is insufficient spacing between the lines in the MWE, made using an `\hbox` filled with two `\vtop` boxes.

```
\parindent=0pt

\newdimen\linewidth
\linewidth=4in

\newdimen\colsep
\colsep=1em

\newdimen\colwidth
\colwidth=0.5\linewidth
\advance\colwidth by -1\colsep

\def\twocols#1#2{%                                                                                                                          
    \hbox to \linewidth{%                                                                                                                   
      \vtop{\hsize=\colwidth
        \hangindent=1em \hangafter=1 #1\par}\hfill
      \vtop{\hsize=\colwidth
        \hangindent=1em \hangafter=1 #2\par}\hss
    }\par
}

\twocols
  {This is a very long line that will run over}
  {What is wrong with the spacing?}
\twocols
  {What is wrong with the spacing?}
  {This is a very long line that will run over}

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34971/how-to-keep-a-constant-baselineskip-when-using-minipages-or-parboxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you turn on logging you see the dreaded

```
..\glue(\lineskip) 1.0
```

a vtop box has large depth, and the following vtop tries to maintain `\baselineskip` spacing to the reference point of the previous box which is the baseline of the first line.  As that can not be achieved, TeX gives up on baseline spacing and just inserts `\lineskip` glue.

You can use a strut at the start and the end, and suppress lineskip glue then spacing will be preserved as long as there is no abnormally large text

[image]

```
\tracingonline1
\tracingoutput1

\showboxdepth=4

\parindent=0pt

\newdimen\linewidth
\linewidth=4in

\newdimen\colsep
\colsep=1em

\newdimen\colwidth
\colwidth=0.5\linewidth
\advance\colwidth by -1\colsep

\def\twocols#1#2{%
    \hbox to \linewidth{% 
      \vtop{\hsize=\colwidth
        \hangindent=1em \hangafter=1 \strut#1\nobreak\strut\par}\hfill
      \vtop{\hsize=\colwidth
        \hangindent=1em \hangafter=1 \strut#2\nobreak\strut\par}\hss
    }\par
}

\twocols
  {This is a very long line that will run over}
  {What is wrong with the spacing?}
\nointerlineskip
\twocols
  {What is wrong with the spacing?}
  {This is a very long line that will run over}

\bye
```

Comment: Could you give an example? (I tried `\vtop spread \baselineskip` but it added too much space.) Also, is this the right way to make such boxes at all?

Comment: @AndrewCashner no you should be using latex:-)

Answer (score 6):

You can carry over the depth of the last line in the `\vtop`:

```
\parindent=0pt

\newdimen\linewidth
\linewidth=4in

\newdimen\colsep
\colsep=1em

\newdimen\colwidth
\colwidth=0.5\linewidth
\advance\colwidth by -1\colsep

\def\twocols#1#2{%
  \par
  \setbox0=\vtop{\hsize=\colwidth
    \hangindent=1em \hangafter=1 #1\par
    \xdef\tpdA{\the\prevdepth}
  }%
  \setbox2=\vtop{\hsize=\colwidth
    \hangindent=1em \hangafter=1 #2\par
    \xdef\tpdB{\the\prevdepth}
  }%
  \edef\tpd{\ifdim\dp0>\dp2 \tpdA \else \tpdB\fi}%
  \hbox to \linewidth{\box0 \hfill \box2}
  \prevdepth=\tpd
}

\twocols
  {This is a very long line that will run over over over over over over over}
  {What is wrong with the spacing?}
\twocols
  {What is wrong with the spacing?}
  {This is a very long line that will run over}

\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update handles the lineskip. Don't use this too close to bottom of page.

```
\parindent=0pt

\newdimen\linewidth
\linewidth=4in

\newdimen\colsep
\colsep=1em

\newdimen\colwidth
\colwidth=0.5\linewidth
\advance\colwidth by -1\colsep

\def\twocols#1#2{%
    \par
    \hbox to\linewidth
    {%
      \vtop{\hsize=\colwidth
        \hangindent=1em \hangafter=1 #1\par\indent}\hfill
      \vtop{\hsize=\colwidth
        \hangindent=1em \hangafter=1 #2\par\indent}%
    }\kern-\baselineskip\hrule height0pt
    \indent\par
}

\lineskip\maxdimen

\twocols
  {This is a very long line that will run over over over over over over over ppppp}
  {Nothing wrong with
  the spacing !}
\twocols
  {Nothing \smash{\vrule height \baselineskip depth 0pt  width 1pt} wrong with
  the spacing! YYYYYY ppppppp}
  {This is a very long line that will run over}

AAAAAA\smash{\vrule height \baselineskip depth 0pt  width 1pt}

\showboxbreadth \maxdimen \showboxdepth \maxdimen

\tracingoutput1
\bye
```

> [image]

---

Here is a a third approach. Does not use `\prevdepth` neither `\strut`'s (the latter forces its use also if you follow the thing with something else than `\twocols` itself).

```
\parindent=0pt

\newdimen\linewidth
\linewidth=4in

\newdimen\colsep
\colsep=1em

\newdimen\colwidth
\colwidth=0.5\linewidth
\advance\colwidth by -1\colsep

\def\twocols#1#2{%
    \par
    \hbox to\linewidth
    {%
      \vtop{\hsize=\colwidth
        \hangindent=1em \hangafter=1 #1\par\indent}\hfill
      \vtop{\hsize=\colwidth
        \hangindent=1em \hangafter=1 #2\par\indent}%
    }\par\kern-\baselineskip\indent\par
}

\twocols
  {This is a very long line that will run over over over over over over jjjjj over}
  {What is wrong with the spacing?}
\twocols
  {What is wrong with the spacing?}
  {This is a very long line that will run over}

\bye
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: you have an additional 1pt  (`\lineskip`) between the boxes still: `..\kern -12.0
..\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
..\glue(\lineskip) 1.0`

Comment: The same as for Gustavo applies here: try `$\Bigg|$` at the end of the very first box.

Comment: @egreg there is an approval vote of your comment, but the `$\Bigg|$` elicits no surprise for me, to the contrary, this is was it aimed at here.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti yes, oversight from copying David's answer as starting point ;-) although I had removed the unneeded  `\hss`... ;-)

Comment: @jfbu The result is clearly unacceptable; is this what you were trying to say? So the answer serves no purpose, doesn't it?

Comment: @egreg I don't know what is the purpose of the OP. I thus interpreted it as `maintain baselineskip separation` and advanced an amusing approach which has even more defects than what appears to you as being one (I am surprised you didn't ask what happens at bottom of page). There is the lineskip glue I didn't check for as pointed out by David.  I had upvoted your answer earlier posting mine as it was the obvious right thing. But this does not mean one can not try other fun approaches.

Comment: @egreg "maintain baselineskip separation" under **normal** circumstances. I make this more precise because I don't want that people think I pretended the code would maintain it in all circumstances. With objects of big depth, the result is not acceptable, I agree on that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I should have checked. See update.

Comment: I removed my comment about the superfluous `\par`: suggest you do the same with your reply.  (This comment will be deleted as well.)

Comment: Instead of `\hrule height 0pt` you could just say `\nointerlineskip`: it’s the same. I think that yours is an interesting idea, and that it is always good to show different approaches: readers might find this instructive.  I also appreciate your point about the `\parskip` glue. +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, why not just the following, then?

```
\parindent=0pt

\newdimen\linewidth
\linewidth=4in

\newdimen\colsep
\colsep=1em

\newdimen\colwidth
\colwidth=0.5\linewidth
\advance\colwidth by -\colsep

\def\singlebox#1{%
  \vtop{%
    \hsize=\colwidth
    \hangindent=1em \hangafter=1
    \leavevmode #1\par
    \kern -\prevdepth
  }%
}
\def\twocols#1#2{%
    \par
    \hbox to\linewidth
    {%
      \singlebox{#1}\hfill\singlebox{#2}%
    }%
    \prevdepth = 0pt
}

\twocols
  {This is a very long line that will run over over over over over over jjjjj over}
  {What is wrong with the spacing?}
\twocols
  {What is wrong with the spacing?}
  {This is a very long line that will run over}

More text.

% {\tracingall\showlists}

\bye
```

Quite obviously, since it “kills” the depth of the bottom line inside the `\twocols` construction, this solution is not adequate when the text contains unusual descenders (as egreg has immediately noticed).  This answer was intended just as a streamlining of jfbu’s idea.

A possible refinement is:

```
\parindent=0pt

\newdimen\linewidth
\linewidth=4in

\newdimen\colsep
\colsep=1em

\newdimen\colwidth
\colwidth=0.5\linewidth
\advance\colwidth by -\colsep

\def\singlebox#1{%
  \vtop{%
    \hsize=\colwidth
    \hangindent=1em \hangafter=1
    \leavevmode #1\par
    \kern -%
      \ifdim\prevdepth<\maxdepth
        \prevdepth
      \else
        \maxdepth
      \fi
  }%
}
\def\twocols#1#2{%
    \par
    \hbox to\linewidth
    {%
      \singlebox{#1}\hfill\singlebox{#2}%
    }%
    \prevdepth = 0pt
}

\twocols
  {This is a very long line that will run over over over over over over jjjjj over}
  {What is wrong with the spacing?}
\twocols
  {What is wrong with the spacing?}
  {This is a very long line that will run over}

More text.

\twocols
  {This is a very long line that will run over over over over over over jjjjj 
  over $\Bigg|$}
  {What is wrong with the spacing?}
\twocols
  {What is wrong with the spacing?}
  {This is a very long line that will run over}

Still more text.

% {\tracingall\showlists}

\bye
```

The output produced by this amended code is

[image: Output of amended code]

Please note that this *does* work at the bottom of pages too.  Moreover, since the OP didn’t insert the `\parskip` glue above the `\twocols` construction, I did not too; if desired, an explicit `\vskip\parskip` can be added just before the `\hbox` command in the definition of `\twocols`.

Comment: Try with `$\Bigg|$` at the end of the very first box and you'll have a surprise.

Comment: @egreg: Ah, yes, of course: I was not even trying to cope with a situation like that.  Mine was just an elaboration over jfbu’s answer.

Comment: Good approach with `\prevdepth`. Solves the issue of behaviour at page bottom from my imaginative proposal.  I think egreg is taking a nap. Else he would be asking about why your method does not inserted `\parskip` glue as it arguably should between two `\twocols`.  Ah yes, his answer does not either. Nobody is perfect. Especially when the world is open ended and answers matter more than questions.

Comment: @jfbu: I think egreg has been silenced by the `\maxdepth` trick… ;-)