# Conditional input of a file depending on a keyword that its contains

Tags: conditionals, include

I have several files containing each an exercise and to make a document I include a set of this files. Some of them need a special treatment so I need a to make a conditional input command that test a keyword on the first line of this file before include it.

Some files begin with :

```
\begin{minipage}
```

The other :

```
something else
```

I want to add an `\item` before the inclusion only if the file doesn't begin with `\begin{minipage}`

Comment: Related: https://ctan.org/pkg/catchfile

Comment: are you committed to that syntax? It would be a bit easier if first lines were `\typeA` and `\typeB`, not comments.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In fact I need to know if the first latex command is `\begin{minipage` or not.

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't understand what is the purpose of this package.

Comment: @Tarass With that package you can read a file to a macro which you can then parse for specified tokens.

Comment: @HenriMenke That is what I understood, but I expected an example in the documentation. I'll try that.

Comment: @HenriMenke Ok I have caught the file, but how parse it ?

Comment: @Tarass I added a solution based on the new information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proof of concept, as details are missing from the question. The `\tarassinput` command inputs the file only if the first line agrees with the second argument.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{typea.tex}
% type A
here latex stuff
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{typeb.tex}
% type B
here latex stuff
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newread\tarass@read
\newcommand{\tarassinput}[2]{%
  % #1 is the name of the file, #2 is the first line
  \openin\tarass@read=#1\relax
  \begingroup\catcode`\%=12
  \edef\tarass@tempa{\@percentchar\space#2\space}%
  \read\tarass@read to\tarass@tempb
  \closein\tarass@read
  \ifx\tarass@tempa\tarass@tempb
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\endgroup\input{#1}}%
  {\endgroup}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Yes: \tarassinput{typea}{type A}

No: \tarassinput{typeb}{type A}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now that more information is available, here's a possibility with `l3regex`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{typea.tex}
here latex stuff
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{typeb.tex}
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
here latex stuff
\end{minipage}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tarassinput}{m}
 {
  \tl_set_from_file:Nnn \l_tarass_input_tl { } { #1 }
  % \A matches the start
  % \c{begin} matches \begin
  % \cB. matches any "group begin" token
  % \cE. matches any "group end" token
  \regex_match:nVF { \A \c{begin} \cB. minipage \cE. } \l_tarass_input_tl { \item }
  \tl_use:N \l_tarass_input_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnF { nV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item Start

\tarassinput{typea}

\tarassinput{typeb}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My mistake, I edit my question to be more specific.

Comment: Why the `\space` after `#2` in `\tarass@tempa`?  Does TeX automatically convert the newline to space even though it is at that point undecided whether a second newline will follow?

Comment: @HenriMenke Because of the end-of-line. I do know about it, don't I? `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Works just fine. I add an optional parameter for the item[...]. Thanks for the comments, I will take a look at l3 syntax and son on.

Comment: @egreg Need some more help on it with vertical spacing between minipages, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304398/vertical-spacing-in-list-latex3-syntax

Comment: @Tarass Sorry, but I don't understand what you're trying to do. What “usual space” are you referring to? Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34971/how-to-keep-a-constant-baselineskip-when-using-minipages-or-parboxes can be useful

Comment: @egreg Yes it is exactly the problem. You can see that the third point is too close to the second. I want to prevent that. I'll study your link.

Comment: @egreg I understand what is in the link, but I'm stuck with l3 syntax. I read the begining of the doc, and understand the name syntax with the _ and :, but don't clearly sen the groups and the real meaning of each command you used.

Comment: @egreg My idea is to save `\prevdepth` in the command and restore in on the next item use. There is nothing else between to tarassinput.

Comment: @egreg You said in the link `For the bottom you can reinstate after the minipage the depth of the last row`. But the problem comes before the minipage. Then \prevdepth is not the solution, is it ?

Comment: @Tarass I have no idea whatsoever about your aim, apart from this strange request of conditionally adding `\item`.  Anyway, your `\begin{minipage}` should be `\begin{minipage}[b]`; before `\end{minipage}` you need to add `\par\edef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}` and after `\tl_use:N \l_tarass_input_tl` you need `\par\prevdepth\tpd` in case of a minipage. But this problem appears to me like something I'd never try to do.