# Control the vertical spacing of the parbox relative to image

Tags: graphics

How can I control the vertical spacing of the parbox relative to the image?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, inner=1in, outer=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=normalsize,skip=10pt}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

        \begin{figure}[!htb]
            \centering
            \caption{}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{untitled.png}
            \parbox{\textwidth}{\footnotesize Hallo}
        \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: By vertical spacing, are you referring to the space *between* the image and the `\parbox`?

Comment: parboxes and images are positioned like letters you have includegraphics followed by parbox with one word-space in between, but as they are full width they are on separate lines. It is better to put them in separate paragraphs so leave a blank line between, you can insert `\vspace{2cm}` or whatever you need after the blank line brefore the parbox

Comment: @werner yes, I was referring to the space between the image and the \parbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current image is set to the width of the text - `\textwidth`. In a landscape image this will be fixed, with the `height` adjusted to match. I assume this is a more preferred resizing as an image of `height=\textheight` will cause overfull `\vbox` issues in the output since you also include a `\caption`.

Based on the above assumption *and* the fact that you're setting a `\parbox` of width `\textwidth`, you can insert any `\vspace{<len>}` between the two components - image and paragraph - to obtain a gap of desired choice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
  {\centering \caption{Figure caption}}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image}

  \vspace{5\baselineskip}% Or whatever length you want

  {\footnotesize \strut
  Some text
  \strut\par}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note the following requirements/changes:

- `\centering` is only applied to the `\caption`, as the other components are set to occupy a block of width `\textwidth`;
- a blank line between the image and the following paragraph to ensure you're in vertical mode. This allows for the proper placement of the `\vspace`;
- Setting of the paragraph with additional `\strut`s as well as an ending `\par` to obtain a proper baseline representation (`\parbox` are known to have [visual issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/5764) regarding this).

Comment: Is there a way to set the note according to width of the image?  So that it doesn't cover the textwidth. I'm using the code you wrote in your answer.

Comment: @S.Ming: So if your image ends up having a width < `\textwidth`, you want to set the note at the bottom to also be in a box that has the same < `\textwidth` width?

Comment: Yes, so that the width of the note equals the width of the image. I know how to do it with \parbox but not with the code you wrote in your answer.

Comment: @S.Ming: In your preamble, add `\newsavebox{\imagebox}`, then in the `figure` environment you can use `\savebox{\imagebox}{\includegraphics[..]{...}}\usebox{\imagebox}`. This way you store the image inside a box (and then set that box immediately) of which one can measure the width. This allows you to set the note inside a `\parbox{\wd\imagebox}{..}`.