# Two \parbox besides eachother in a tabular

Tags: tabularx

i made the folowing commands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{calc}


\newcounter{som}
\newcounter{sub}
\setcounter{som}{1}
\setcounter{sub}{1}

\definecolor{Som}{RGB}{240,185,134}

\newcommand{\opg}[1]{\setcounter{sub}{1}
                                            \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{ 
                                           \begin{tabular}{p{1cm} p{\textwidth-1cm}}
                                            \colorbox{Som}{\color{white}\textbf{\arabic{som}}} & 
                                              \parbox[t]{\textwidth-1cm}{#1} \cr
                                           \end{tabular}
                                          }
                                          \addtocounter{som}{1}
                                            }   

\newcommand{\opgs}[1]{\parbox[t]{\textwidth-1cm}{
                                                    \hspace{-0.29cm}
                                                    \begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm} p{\textwidth-0.5cm}}
                                                    \textbf{\alph{sub} \hfill} & 
                                                    #1 \end{tabular} 
                                                    }                                                                                   
                                            \addtocounter{sub}{1}
                                            }

\begin{document}

\opg{Bla bla bla $P$ bla bla bla bla bla bla $h_2(\frac{5}{3})$. bla bla blabla bla bla $t=\frac{5}{3}$
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla $h_3$  bla bla bla bla bla bla $P$ aan het
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla $P$  bla bla bla bla bla bla 2. 
\opgs{Bla bla bla $P$ bla bla bla bla bla bla $h_2(\frac{5}{3})$. bla bla blabla bla bla $t=\frac{5}{3}$
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla $h_3$  bla bla bla bla bla bla $P$ aan het
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla $P$  bla bla bla bla bla bla 2. }
\opgs{bla bla bla bla bla $h_2(\frac{5}{3})$. bla bla blabla bla bla $t=\frac{5}{3}$}}

\vspace{2cm}

\opg{\opgs{Bla bla bla $P$ bla bla bla bla bla bla $h_2(\frac{5}{3})$. bla bla blabla bla bla $t=\frac{5}{3}$
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla $h_3$  bla bla bla bla bla bla $P$ aan het
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla $P$  bla bla bla bla bla bla 2. }
\opgs{Bla bla bla $P$ bla bla bla bla bla bla $h_2(\frac{5}{3})$. bla bla blabla bla bla $t=\frac{5}{3}$
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla $h_3$  bla bla bla bla bla bla $P$ aan het
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla $P$  bla bla bla bla bla bla 2. }}

\end{document}
```

And it went wrong: See the picture: [image]

The number 2 is not at the same high as the a, but the number 1 is. Number 2 should also be at the same high. What went wrong, and how can I correct this?
Thanks, Bert

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Okay, i did. See above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a number of changes to `\opg` and `\opgs`, mainly focused on using [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). I've avoided nesting `\parbox`es in lieu of [How to keep a constant baselineskip when using `minipage`s (or `\parbox`es)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/5764)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,tabularx}

\newcounter{som}
\newcounter{sub}[som]% Counter sub will reset with every step of counter som

\definecolor{Som}{RGB}{240,185,134}

\newcommand{\opg}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{som}%
  \par\noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} p{1cm} X @{}}
    \colorbox{Som}{\color{white}\textbf{\arabic{som}}} & 
      #1
  \end{tabularx}
}   

\newcommand{\opgs}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{sub}%
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{@{} p{5mm} X @{}}
    \textbf{\alph{sub}} & 
      #1
  \end{tabularx} 
}

\begin{document}

\opg{Bla bla bla $P$ bla bla bla bla bla bla $h_2(\frac{5}{3})$. bla bla blabla bla bla $t=\frac{5}{3}$
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla $h_3$  bla bla bla bla bla bla $P$ aan het
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla $P$  bla bla bla bla bla bla 2. 
  \opgs{Bla bla bla $P$ bla bla bla bla bla bla $h_2(\frac{5}{3})$. bla bla blabla bla bla $t=\frac{5}{3}$
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla $h_3$  bla bla bla bla bla bla $P$ aan het
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla $P$  bla bla bla bla bla bla 2. }
  \opgs{bla bla bla bla bla $h_2(\frac{5}{3})$. bla bla blabla bla bla $t=\frac{5}{3}$}%
}

\vspace{2cm}

\opg{%
  \opgs{Bla bla bla $P$ bla bla bla bla bla bla $h_2(\frac{5}{3})$. bla bla blabla bla bla $t=\frac{5}{3}$
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla $h_3$  bla bla bla bla bla bla $P$ aan het
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla $P$  bla bla bla bla bla bla 2. }
  \opgs{Bla bla bla $P$ bla bla bla bla bla bla $h_2(\frac{5}{3})$. bla bla blabla bla bla $t=\frac{5}{3}$
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla $h_3$  bla bla bla bla bla bla $P$ aan het
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla $P$  bla bla bla bla bla bla 2. }%
}

\end{document}
```

Within `\opgs`, the `tabularx` is aligned at the `[t]`op to ensure it aligns vertically with the `\colorbox` number (if needed).

Note that the `tabular`-like construction makes your "list" unbreakable across the page boundary.

Comment: Perfect! 
Could you tell me something more about:

Comment: \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} p{1cm} X @{}}

Comment: What does it do? I want to learn...

Comment: @BertBooltink: `tabularx` is different from the regular `tabular` in the sense that it takes a width argument as well, and requires the use of at least one `X`-column. The `X` column will fill in the remainder of the width specification left after the other columns have been set. That way *you* don't have to do any calculations. `@{}` removes the inter-column space; in my code that removes what may look like an indent on the left/right of the table.