# How to center \quad element in \cventry

Tags: positioning, moderncv, qrcode

I would like to center qrcode in cventry. Implemented solution (quad + qrcode) could be replaced.

Current code (MWE):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}  
\moderncvstyle{classic}                                                  
\usepackage[scale=0.87]{geometry}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\name{}{}      

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum}
\cventry
{Lorem -- ipsum}
{dolor sit amet}{}{}{}
{a urna ut auctor. Proin venenatis lacus vitae eros posuere, id pretium tortor rutrum. Donec ac auctor nunc. Suspendisse libero nibh, iaculis blandit tellus ac, faucibus euismod purus. Sed quis lacus vel nunc dictum aliquet. Sed hendrerit ultrices nisi non facilisis.
\quad
\qrcode[height=0.5in]{qrcode message}
\qquad
}
\end{document}
```

Current state:
[image: Current]

State i would like to achieve:
[image: Correct]

I was trying to use

```
\hfill
```

but without success.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a *full* MWE. Maybe you should have a look at `\parbox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the text argument within a `[t]`op-aligned `\parbox` that has a pre-specified width (of exactly `\linewidth-.5in-1em`, leaving `.5in` for the QR code on the right, as well as a `\quad` or `1em` gap):

[image]

```
\cventry
  {Lorem -- ipsum}
  {dolor sit amet}
  {consectetur}
  {adipiscing, elit}
  {\newline\textbf{Nullam:} mattis}
  {\parbox[t]{\linewidth-.5in-1em}{\strut
    a urna ut auctor. Proin venenatis lacus vitae eros posuere, id pretium tortor rutrum. 
    Donec ac auctor nunc. Suspendisse libero nibh, iaculis blandit tellus ac, faucibus euismod purus. 
    Sed quis lacus vel nunc dictum aliquet. Sed hendrerit ultrices nisi non facilisis.\strut}\hfill
    \raisebox{-\height+.7\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\qrcode[height=0.5in]{qrcode message}}%
  }
```

The QR code is "raised" to align at the top of the `\parbox`. Note the use of `\strut` at the start and end of the `\parbox` content in order to ensure a [consistent baseline skip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/5764).

I used [`template.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex) as base for the above example.