# How can I set up the space in the end of the minipage environment with baselineskip automatically?

Tags: minipage, book-design, baseline

In the below code, how can I set up the space in the `end` of the `minipage` environment with `baselineskip` `automatically`? 
Actually I don't want use to `\vspace...` and the same command, and also I want to be `all` of my minipages with `[t]` option.
**My code:**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.46\linewidth}
 If you face a problem try to find the solution not the reason.
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.46\linewidth}
 If you face a problem try to find the solution not the reason.
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
 If you face a problem try to find the solution not the reason.
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
 If you face a problem try to find the solution not the reason.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

**My output**

---

[image]

---

**Second edit:**
I want the space between my lines to be the same (inside and outside the minipage)
**I want to have the below output:**

---

[image]

---

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34971/ help?

Comment: Thanks my master egreg. actually no, whenever i use \baselinestretch command it doesn't work correctly. Please see my output with [t] option.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understand the question. Is this the output that you want?

[image]

To get this I defined a new environment called `Minipage` that inserts a `[t]-minipage` environment with a default line width of `\linewidth`and which adds `\newline\vspace\baselineskip` at the end of the environment. The environment always accepts an optional environment for changing the line width. Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newenvironment{Minipage}[1][1]{\minipage[t]{#1\linewidth}}{\endminipage\newline\vspace\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\begin{Minipage}[0.46]
 If you face a problem try to find the solution not the reason.
\end{Minipage}\hfill
\begin{Minipage}[0.46]
 If you face a problem try to find the solution not the reason.
\end{Minipage}
\begin{Minipage}
 If you face a problem try to find the solution not the reason.
\end{Minipage}
\begin{Minipage}
 If you face a problem try to find the solution not the reason.
\end{Minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my dear Andrew. but I didn't mean it. I change your macro in this way:
`\newenvironment{Minipage}[1][1]{\minipage[t]{#1\linewidth}}{\endminipage\vspace\baselineskip}`
It is ok, but now I want the space between my lines to be the same (inside and outside the minipage).

Comment: I edit my question and  I show that what I want with the image.