# space between two vbox

Tags: spacing, boxes

I have two vboxes and I want space between two vbox be exactly same as space between two line of paragraph.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\linespread{2}
\begin{document}
    \setbox0=\vbox{\lipsum[1]}
    \setbox1=\vbox{\lipsum[2]}
    \unvbox0
    \unvbox1
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `\addvspace{\baselineskip}`

Comment: related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34971/how-to-keep-a-constant-baselineskip-when-using-minipages-or-parboxes

Comment: @YiannisLazarides no:-) (see the link touhami gives)

Comment: actually your question is confusing, you ask about the space between two vbox but your example unboxes them, different issues arise in getting the space between two unboxed lists and between two boxes, so you should clarify which you want.

Comment: Can you please give more details about why you'd like to do such a thing?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides this add extra space more than distance between two line. Thanks

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I dint know difference between \box and \unvbox. I will ask this in another question. Thanks. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438099

Comment: By use of this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438099 I could set space between two vbox  exactly equal to \baselineskip. But How set space between two unvbox to be exactly equal to \baselineskip. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When lists are unboxed, TeX does not re-calculate baseline-to-baseline spacing, the contents of the boxes are simply added directly to the current list.

So (when feasible) it is simplest to arrange that the list being unboxed have the correct spacing. In this case the main controlling parameter is `\prevdepth`, if you force the paragraph to end before ending the first box, you can save `\prevdepth` and then set `\prevdepth` at the start of the second box to force the correct baselineskip calculation for the first line,

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\linespread{2}
\begin{document}
    \setbox0=\vbox{\lipsum[1]\par\global\dimen1=\prevdepth}
    \setbox2=\vbox{\prevdepth=\dimen1 \lipsum[2]}
    \unvbox0
    \unvbox2
\end{document}
```