# Can somebody tell me where I am going wrong here?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, documentclass-writing

I am trying to write a CV. I have no previous experience of using latex.

This is my .cls file that I have written:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{Arpon_cv}[2018/09/28 Arpon's custom CV class]
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\datedsection}[2]{%
\section[#1]{#1 \hfill #2}%
}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\Large\scshape\raggedright\ttfamily}
  {}{0em}
  {}
  [\titlerule]
\newcommand{\datedsubsection}[2]{%
  \subsection[#1]{#1 \hfill #2}%
}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\large\scshape\raggedright\ttfamily}
  {}{0em}
   {}
\newcommand{\vugichugi}[2]{%
  \subsubsection[#1]{#1 \hfill #2}%
}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalsize\scshape\raggedright\ttfamily}
  {}{0em}
  {}
```

This is my .tex file:

```
\documentclass{Arpon_cv}
\begin{document}
\datedsection{Education}{}
     \datedsubsection{Bachelor of Science}{2015-Now}
         \vugichugi{University of Dhaka, Dhaka, Bangladesh}{}
         \vugichugi{Current CGPA (Up to 6th Semester): 3.72}{}
     \datedsubsection{Higher Secondary Certificate}{2014}
         \vugichugi{St. Joseph Higher Secondary School, Dhaka, Bangladesh}{}
         \vugichugi{GPA: 5.00 out of 5.00}{}
     \datedsubsection{Secondary School Certificate}{2012}
         \vugichugi{St. Joseph Higher Secondary School, Dhaka, Bangladesh}{}
         \vugichugi{GPA: 5.00 out of 5.00}{}

\datedsection{Standardized Tests}{}
     \datedsubsection{Graduate Record Examination (GRE)}{2018}
         \vugichugi{Total- 329. Quantitative Reasoning: 170, Verbal Reasoning: 159 Analytical Writing Analysis: 5.0}{}
     \datedsubsection{Test Of English as a Foreign Language (TOEFL)}{2018}
         \vugichugi{Total: 111. Reading: 29, Listening: 29, Speaking: 27, Writing: 26}{}

\datedsection{Research Interests}{}

\datedsection{Research Experience}{}
     \datedsubsection{Undergraduate Thesis}{Sept 2018-Now}
         \vugichugi{Title: Computer code development for steady-state neutronics analysis of a novel reactor core.}{}
         \vugichugi{Description: I am currently working on developing a computer code to numerically approximate the steady-state neutronics of a novel reactor core.}{} 
     \datedsubsection{Undergraduate Project}{Sept 2017-March 2018}
         \vugichugi{Title: Demonstration of axial neutron flux distribution in a hypothetical reactor core employing control pellets (control material in pellet form).}{}
         \vugichugi{Description: I demonstrated an evenly balanced axial flux distribution that can be generated if hypothetical control pellets (control material in pellet form) are used instead of regular single-piece control rods. Regular control rods generate uneven axial flux distribution when partially inserted.}{}

\datedsection{Industrial Attachment}{}
     \datedsubsection{Institute of Electronics}{March 2018-April 2018}
         \vugichugi{Atomic Energy Research Establishment (AERE), Savar, Dhaka, Bangladesh.}{}
         \vugichugi{A facility of Bangladesh Atomic Energy Commission (BAEC)}{}

\datedsection{Prizes, Awards and Grants}{}
     \datedsubsection{}{}

\datedsection{Work Experience}{}
     \datedsubsection{Administrative Experience}{??}
     \datedsubsection{Teaching Experience}{??}

\datedsection{Volunteer Work}{}

\datedsection{Computer and Programming Skills}{}

\end{document}
```

When I compile the .tex file, the first page of the output pdf comes out blank.
[image]
The Header "Education" starts from the second page. And nothing below the "Industrial Attachment" section is printed. All the sections after that is just lost. 
[image]
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please add MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that as copyable code, not as screenshots.

Comment: Is it okay now? Please help me clear up this confusion.

Comment: @CampanIgnis I edited my post now. Please take a look

Comment: The problem seem to me that you typeset everything as section, subsection, and subsubsection and thus misusing those elements. I cannot help you more here, at the moment.

Comment: then what can I do to remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not define the parts of your resume/cv upon the various sectioning commands.  I would just create what you want from *scratch*.  There's a lot going on in the sectioning commands that you really don't need here, and part of this is what's creating issues for you.

I've redefined your three primary commands as follows:

```
\newcommand\datedsection[2]{%%
  \addvspace{3ex}%%
  \noindent\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[-2pt]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}%%
  {\Large\scshape\ttfamily#1\hspace{\fill}#2}\par\addvspace{2ex}
  }

\newcommand\datedsubsection[2]{%%
  \addvspace{1ex}%%
  \noindent{\large\scshape\ttfamily#1\hspace{\fill}#2}\par\addvspace{1ex}}

\newcommand\vugichugi[2]{%%
  \noindent{\normalsize\scshape\ttfamily#1\hspace{\fill}#2}\par}
```

which results in output such as:

[image]

It's not altogether identical to your output, but very similar.

Using `\addvspace` has the pleasant effect that it only inserts the largest of multiple vertical space being added.

I'd recommend defining a titling and description command of some sort.  Something along the lines of:

```
\makeatletter

\def\ae@title{\ttfamily\scshape Title:}%%
\newlength\ae@title@width

\newcommand\mytitle[1]{%%                                                             
  %% set the length here in case there are formatting commands                        
  %% that might effect the appearance of the 'TITLE'                                  
  \settowidth\ae@title@width{\ae@title}%% comment to avoid unwanted whitespace
  \noindent
  {\ae@title}%%
  \hspace{\fill}%%                                 
  %% set width of parbox to remaining space on line minus `1em` of
  %% space between title and the parbox itself  
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\columnwidth-\ae@title@width-1em}%%
     {\raggedright\textit{#1}%%
      %% calculate the proper depth of the box
      \par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}}%%
  \par%% switch to vmode to allow `\addvspace to do its magic
  \addvspace{1ex}%%          
  \prevdepth\tpd}%% measure the depth to get interline spacing more properly adjusted 


\newcommand\mydescription[1]{%%
  \ttfamily{\scshape Description:} #1\par\addvspace{1ex}}

\makeatother
```

which produces this appearance:

[image]

There are a couple of things I'm doing here which might be of interest.
For one, `\columnwidth` and `\textwidth` are not necessarily the same.  Generally, I feel `\columnwidth` is *safer* if you have a document that might have multple columns, for example.  Note, I did use `\textwidth` for the section header `\datedsection`.

Next, I used a `\parbox` to get a particular effect to show off the title.  You may or may not like this style.  If you want to keep it though, then it's useful to understand what's going on with `\prevdepth`.  Essentially, I'm *correcting* how LaTeX takes into account the depth of the `minipage` or `\parbox`.  See egreg's answer to [How to keep a constant baselineskip when using minipages (or \parboxes)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34982/22413) which nicely explains this trick I'm using.

Finally, I'm not so sure of the wisdom of bludgeoning your reader with so much capitalization.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. This solved the problem.