# Getting the proper interline spacing after a minipage environment

Tags: tex-core, minipage

I have a `TikZ` diagram to the right of a `minipage` environment. I have some text that I want under the `minipage` environment. The interline spacing is about half of the other interline spacing.

I don't insist on using a `minipage` here. I just want the appropriate typesetting.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}


\begin{document}



\noindent \begin{minipage}[t]{4.875in}
\noindent \raggedright{\textbf{1.) }The following figure depicts three congruent semicircles bounded by another \\
semicircle; the diameters of the three smaller semicircles cover the diameter of \\
the bigger semicircle, and each of the three smaller semicircles is tangent to \\
two other semicircles at the endpoints of its diameter. \textit{A} is the area of \\
of the region enclosed by the three smaller semicircles and \textit{B} is the area}
\end{minipage}
%
\hspace{-0.25cm}
%
\raisebox{0mm}[0mm][0mm]
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north west)]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[fill=blue!50] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) arc (0:180:1.5) -- cycle;
%
\draw[fill=yellow] (-3/2,0) -- (-1/2,0) arc (0:180:1/2) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=yellow] (-1/2,0) -- (1/2,0) arc (0:180:1/2) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=yellow] (1/2,0) -- (3/2,0) arc (0:180:1/2) -- cycle;

\draw[fill] (O) circle (1.5pt);


\end{tikzpicture}
} \\
the region enclosed by the big semicircle but outside the three smaller semicircles. Compute the ratio of $A : B$.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/4427?

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at [How to keep a constant baselineskip when using minipages (or \parboxes)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/4427) but there's a much better alternative:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}


\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{4.875in}\raggedright
\textbf{1.)} The following figure depicts three congruent semicircles 
bounded by another semicircle; the diameters of the three smaller 
semicircles cover the diameter of the bigger semicircle, and each of 
the three smaller semicircles is tangent to two other semicircles at 
the endpoints of its diameter. $A$ is the area of of the region 
enclosed by the three smaller semicircles and $B$ is the area\par
\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\raisebox{0mm}[0mm][0mm]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north west)]

  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
  \draw[fill=blue!50] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) arc (0:180:1.5) -- cycle;
  %
  \draw[fill=yellow] (-3/2,0) -- (-1/2,0) arc (0:180:1/2) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=yellow] (-1/2,0) -- (1/2,0) arc (0:180:1/2) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=yellow] (1/2,0) -- (3/2,0) arc (0:180:1/2) -- cycle;

  \draw[fill] (O) circle (1.5pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\prevdepth=\tpd
\noindent
the region enclosed by the big semicircle but outside the three smaller 
semicircles. Compute the ratio of $A : B$.

\bigskip

\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{3.2cm}
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.south west)]

  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
  \draw[fill=blue!50] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) arc (0:180:1.5) -- cycle;
  %
  \draw[fill=yellow] (-3/2,0) -- (-1/2,0) arc (0:180:1/2) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=yellow] (-1/2,0) -- (1/2,0) arc (0:180:1/2) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=yellow] (1/2,0) -- (3/2,0) arc (0:180:1/2) -- cycle;

  \draw[fill] (O) circle (1.5pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent
\textbf{1.)} The following figure depicts three congruent semicircles 
bounded by another semicircle; the diameters of the three smaller 
semicircles cover the diameter of the bigger semicircle, and each of 
the three smaller semicircles is tangent to two other semicircles at 
the endpoints of its diameter. $A$ is the area of of the region 
enclosed by the three smaller semicircles and $B$ is the area
the region enclosed by the big semicircle but outside the three smaller 
semicircles. Compute the ratio of $A : B$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am looking at your first display. The interline spacing is correct ... but now I would like "two" to be typeset on the fourth line and "the region" to be typeset on the fifth line.

Comment: What does `\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}` instruct `LaTeX` to do?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire Did you read the linked question and answer? I would never alternate ragged right (with manual breaking) for a text such as this. The first way is as wrong as it can be, I added it just for showing the method for preserving the baseline skip.

Comment: What is the difference between using `\raggedright` and manual line breaking?

Comment: I will look at your explanation in the link now.

Comment: I added `\par\xdef\tpd{\region\prevdepth` to the end of the text in the `minipage` environment and `\prevdepth=\tpd` after the `minipage` environment. I get an error saying "\par\xdef\tpd{\region\prevdepth is not a defined control sequence."

Comment: The error is apparently in using `\par\xdef\tpd{\region\prevdepth` instead of `\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth`. Why is there using the code with "region" a mistake? "Region" is the last word in the line, and the "g" in it sets the low below the baseline in the `minipage` environment.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire What's making you into thinking that `\region` is a defined command? I use `\par` to finish the paragraph, after which `\the\prevdepth` will refer to the depth of the last line.

Answer (score 1):

it is not very clear to me what you like to obtain. see, if the my guessing is close to your goal:

[image]

for above result i use the `wrapfig` package:

```
\documentclass[dvipsname]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=blue!50] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) arc (0:180:1.5) -- cycle;
%
\draw[fill=yellow] (-3/2,0) -- (-1/2,0) arc (0:180:1/2) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=yellow] (-1/2,0) -- (1/2,0) arc (0:180:1/2) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=yellow] (1/2,0) -- (3/2,0) arc (0:180:1/2) -- cycle;

\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent\textbf{1.)}
The following figure depicts three congruent semicircles bounded by another
semicircle; the diameters of the three smaller semicircles cover the diameter 
of the bigger semicircle, and each of the three smaller semicircles is tangent 
to two other semicircles at the endpoints of its diameter. $A$ is the area of
of the region enclosed by the three smaller semicircles and $B} is the area
the region enclosed by the big semicircle but outside the three smaller 
semicircles. Compute the ratio of $A : B$.
\end{document}
```