# Create environment that sets minimum size of its contents

Tags: spacing, environments, vertical-spacing

How can I create environment that makes its content at least x units high? It should add white space under its content.

Comment: Is there anything special that should occur when the content appears at the end of the page? For example, should everything be taken to the next page, or should the white space be gobbled?

Comment: The whole environment contents should be considered as one box. If there is not enough space on the page, it should go to the next. The environment will have width = `\textwidth`.

Comment: You say "considered as one box".  Boxes do not break to the next page, so what you are talking about is not a box.

Comment: The whole box should go to the next page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a possible realization (if I have understood the request): the environment is basically a `minipage`, but before the latter starts there is an invisible rule with a given depth. The minimum depth can be passed as optional parameter to the environment. Here I have set the width of the rule to `1pt` in order to show what is happening (which of course results in overfull `\hbox`es) but it should be of course `0pt`.

```
% twocolumn for smaller snapshot
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\newenvironment{foo}[1][8ex]{%
   \par\noindent
   \vrule depth#1 width1pt% <-- WRITE width0pt HERE
   \minipage[t]{\linewidth}%
  }{%
   \par\xdef\next{\the\prevdepth}\endminipage
   \par
   \prevdepth\next
   \ignorespacesafterend
}

\begin{document}

See this and that,
\begin{foo}
Some text here.
\end{foo}
Some other text here.
\begin{foo}
Some longer text here which will take more than one line and in total more
than the 5ex fixed by the invisible (well, not quite) rule on the left of this
strange environment.
\end{foo}
Some other text here.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good but I want to have the environment contents on one page. (When there is not enough space, it should place everything to the next one.)

Comment: @campa, Could you explain the code put into the enddef of the new environment?

Comment: @mcarchmiller Not really, at least not in comments `:-)` Jokes aside, try commenting it out and you'll see why it's needed: the trouble with the `t`-aligned `minipage` (which is inherited by the TeX primitive `\vtop`) is that the baseline distance will be correct with the *preceding* line, but the line *following* the `minipage` will be too close. The `\prevdepth` stuff is a very low-level TeX trick to correct this. I picked that up years ago so I don't have a quick reference, but I'm sure the issue popped out on the site: I can't look for it now, I'll ping you later (or more likely tomorrow).

Comment: @mcarchmiller Oh, wait, here is one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/82917.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a `minipage`, which has the option to set the height.  The problem is that a minipage will set the the indention and paragraph skipping to zero, but you may want to continue with the same format as your document.  The solution is to save those settings and set them in the `minipage`.  I have also made the environment height an optional parameter.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% For saving the current parskip and parindent
\newlength{\saveparskip}
\newlength{\saveparindent}

% Environment with option to set height
\newenvironment{foo}[1][]
    {%
    \par\noindent%
    \setlength{\saveparskip}{\parskip}%
    \setlength{\saveparindent}{\parindent}%
    \begin{minipage}[t][#1]{\linewidth}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{\saveparskip}\setlength{\parindent}{\saveparindent}
    }
    {\strut\end{minipage}\par}

\setlength{\parskip}{2.5ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0in}

\begin{document}

Outside text
\begin{foo}
    This is in the new environment
\end{foo}
outside text
\begin{foo}[1in]
    This is in the new environment with set height
\end{foo}
outside text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good point with the paragraph skip and indent within the `minipage`. However, if the content of the `minipage` is larger than the height set with the optional parameter, the following text will be overwritten.