# How to increase the line spacing for the current line manually

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, vertical-spacing

It is easy to see that the following code will automatically change the line spacing for the line with `{\huge test}` but leave the other part of this paragraph untouched.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \blindtext {\huge test} \blindtext
\end{document}
```

So, my question is how to realize this functionality **manually**. I've tried to change the `\baselineskip` by hand but to my experience it seems that this will change all the line spacing in this paragraph. (Of course, I will have to change it back after the current paragraph to keep the text afterwards untouched.)

Comment: `\vspace{3cm}` if used mid-paragraph will add 3cm of space after just one line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Just like that ```{\huge test}``` only increases the upper spacing, this ```\vspace{3cm}``` method only increases the lower spacing, how can one realize the increase of spacing symmetrically?

Comment: You can use `\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3ex}` (play with the values until they fit your liking).

Comment: Note that `\baselineskip=\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox` if you want to maintain proportionality.  There is also `\vphantom{\huge test}`.

Answer (score 1):

It requires some writing, but a `minipage` will do the job without guesses

```
\begin{minipage}[c][3\baselineskip][c]{5em}\strut \centering \huge test\end{minipage}
```

It will define a box 3 baselineskip   high, slightly wider than its content and have it centered.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}    
    
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.\begin{minipage}[c][3\baselineskip][c]{5em} \strut\centering \huge test\end{minipage} \blindtext
    
\end{document}
```

`\begin{minipage}[position][height][inner-pos]{width} ... \end{minipage}`

The first optional argument `position` governs how the minipage vertically aligns with the surrounding material. (c,t, b)

The second optional argument `height`  sets the height of the minipage.

The final optional argument `inner-pos` controls the vertical placement of contents inside the box.

The solution is not *exact*. The `strut` helps to mitigate the extra vertical space added by the minipage.

For a detailed explanation see [constant-baselineskip-when-using-minipages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34982/161015)

To check the horizontal alignment try `\begin{minipage}[c][1\baselineskip][c]{2em} \strut \centering  test\end{minipage}`

Comment: The baseline is just a bit different for the text in the minipage.  Ideally, it should be the same as for the main text on the same line.